# ¿Son aceptables las traducciones directas de respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, traducciones-de-contenido

Dado el caso de un usuario que escribe una pregunta que ya había sido formulada anteriormente en el sitio principal de StackOverflow, y que en dicho sitio ya tenía una respuesta aceptada (o "aceptable", es decir correcta y probablemente con votos positivos).

¿Es adecuado responder con una simple traducción de dicha respuesta?

Aquí un ejemplo: [¿Cuándo usar y es seguro emplear const_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/cu%c3%a1ndo-usar-y-es-seguro-emplear-const-cast-static-cast-dynamic-cast-reinterp)

Comment: Entiendo que hay consenso, pero tratemos que no se vuelva una carrera de traductores.

Comment: Por supuesto. Yo sólo lo planteo para el caso de preguntas que ya existen de forma idéntica (o muy parecida) en el sitio original y hay alguna **buena** respuesta disponible.

Comment: Si el objetivo fuera traducir todo SO, como parece que hay varios usuarios estan haciendo, o postear muchas preguntas básicas, SO podría haber solicitado voluntarios para traducir preguntas bien establecidas del sitio original.

Answer (score 17):

Sí, es aceptable.

StackOverflow en español nace precisamente para ayudar a los programadores que por la razón que sea no dominan el idioma inglés lo suficiente como para usar el sitio principal. Así que si su duda ya ha sido resuelta por un experto en dicho sitio, ¿por qué no hacer que la información esté disponible para más gente?

Eso sí, es muy recomendable (incluso yo diría que podría hacerse obligatorio) que al principio o al final de la respuesta se añada un enlace a la respuesta original: es de justicia dar crédito a la persona que se tomó la molestia de redactar la respuesta en primer lugar.

Comment: Lo de obligatorio no se, es una cortesia, por otro lado podría acordarse hacerlas "community wiki" answers, esa seria una forma honesta de no llevarse el crédito de otros.

Comment: En realidad no puede ser opcional. Debe ser obligatorio: el contenido de stackoverflow en inglés (y este sitio también) está regido bajo la licencia cc by-sa 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) que especifica que es requerida la atribución al autor original. Mas información aquí: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: Por otro lado, no lo veo necesario convertir en community wiki. Es decir la traducción también es una actividad que merece recompensa. Sin embargo sería recomendable que el traductor sea capaz de argumentar y defender la respuesta original, ya que siempre habrán comentarios de terceros y del autor de la pregutna que requieran mas información por parte del autor/traductor de la respuesta

Comment: ¿Podemos agregar un mensaje diciendo que si la respuesta es una traducción de una respuesta en el sitio de inglés se dé atribución de la forma que plantea la licencia CC?

Comment: Lo de la atribución de hecho esta en las reglas del sitio en Español, solo que aún no esta traducida esa parte. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: Yo creo que no debería haber mayor problema ya que para muchos al no manejar el ingles en su totalidad, para esta población la información generada o publicada en la version inglesa del sitio simplemente no existe, pero concuerdo con que seria adecuado hacer referencia al post en ingles del cual se obtuvo la respuesta

Answer (score 9):

esta bien y va ser divertido! Pero voto por evitarlo durante la beta privada y dejarlo para la beta publica.

Tengo motivos, no me gustaría leer en los diarios...

[image]

Comment: jaja eso del periodico entiendo que es coña no? porque solo el 3 % son originales, no se como explicarlo si eso fuera verdad digo lo del periodico ahora abren en japones entonces uno que pregunta por qué no compila x libreria en c++14, o mejor hace la misma pregunta sobre la que se basa este post y esa misma pregunta esta en ingles, en ruso y ahora aqui, se les otorga la idea original por llamarlo asi, al primero que la pregunto, no se lo veo un tanto raro ademas

Comment: que una pregunta es eso una pregunta que es muy probable que alguien se la plantease mucho antes y la publicara o no en cualquier SO, foro o lo que sea, si cada usuario que va hacer una pregunta tiene que mirar si esta en otro SO para que se crea un SO en su lengua, no se digo yo. Lo aclaro para que no se ofenda nadie,

Comment: a mi si esta en ingles o en chino ----- me de igual, sea la respuesta o la pregunta, si quiero que SO.es funcione es para no tener que estar traduciendo y que pueda entenderlo lo mejor posible y poder contestar y aclara dudas si al realizar alguna respuesta alguien las tiene sobre esta, y hacerlo de manera fluida, yo soy usuario de SO original y rara vez contesto, por variar razones que no son importates en este tema pero una de ellas

Comment: es la anterior el poder responder alguna duda sin problemas por causa del idioma, y vuelvo a recalcar no me molesta para nada que usaras mi pregunta es mas me hiciste reir y gracias por ello Saludos

Comment: P.D: Te dejo un "like" por la foto jaja

Comment: ahh es cierto fallo mio cuando pueda lo muevo de alguna manera es que vi tu nombre y tu ya me entiendes, ahora lo miro y es que es raro ja hizo la pregunta y se contesto quizas por eso me confundi, pero nada solo exprese una opinion pero el like por tu foto te lo ganaste jaja por cierto te deje un ms en el chat

Comment: rnrneverdies, me parece que te equivocaste con el porcentaje, va a ser mas 1% preguntas originales, quizás menos. Me parece que el objetivo del beta se esta desvirtuando completamente.

Comment: En vez de ponerse catastrofistas les animo a que hagan un análisis de porcentajes ahora. La última vez que miré solo había 86 preguntas ;)

Comment: @astrojuanlu muchas son traducciones, pero te comento que este post se escribio hace un mes.

Answer (score 9):

## No solo es válido, sino que debe promoverse.

Considero que las traducciones de preguntas y respuestas de StackOverflow en Inglés al Español no solo es algo válido, sino que **es algo que debemos incentivar** (y no castigar, como se está haciendo actualmente)

Me parece que todos acá están demasiado preocupados por la reputación que ganarán las personas que se den a la tarea de traducir una pregunta o respuesta (o ambas) del StackOverflow en Inglés (y supongo que estarían igual de molestos si se tradujeran preguntas del Ruso o del Portugués).

Yo, en cambio, creo que son justos y merecidos los puntos para quién traduzca una pregunta, trataré de explicar por qué, y para ello, les invito a preguntarnos:

## ¿Cuál es el Objetivo central de es.SO?

Lo que yo veo como objetivo primordial es que es.SO sea el punto de referencia para los programadores de habla hispana. Gente que no necesariamente es fluida en el Inglés y que busca ayuda, que está dispuesta a dar alguna ayuda, y que hará búsquedas en español en Google y será a través del contenido ya existente que llegará al sitio. En este punto, veo a los traductores como verdaderos héroes, dispuestos a traer buena parte del contenido existente ya en Inglés al Español.

Y, si se sabe conducir el proceso, como parte de la traducción, se pueden mejorar las preguntas y las respuestas, por ejemplo, consolidando varias respuestas con información importante en una sola.

Incluso por allí leí una propuesta para marcar como duplicadas en es.SO las preguntas que ya se han hecho en StackOverflow en Inglés, pero seamos sinceros:

## Casi todo se ha preguntado y respondido en StackOverflow en Inglés

Bueno, no casi todo, pero con una comunidad de millones de usuarios y casi 10 años de ventaja, es difícil pensar que hay alguna pregunta básica para la que no exista uno o varios "hilos" en SO.

Es una cantidad y calidad de información que, seamos sinceros, no existe en español.

¿Por qué castigar con votos negativos a los usuarios que están dispuestos a ayudar con esta tarea?

Y finalmente, a medida que la comunidad crezca

## El contenido en español también será creado desde cero

Habrá expertos y novatos participando día a día. Al final, quienes ganamos somos todos los hispanos como conjunto, pero sobre todo, aquellos que aún tienen dificultad para leer y sobre todo escribir/expresarse en Inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Creo esta bien que sea valido, mientras mas información mejor, pero se debería buscar una forma estándar (parte de las reglas del sitio) de indicar que se trata de una traducción directa de la pagina en ingles y algún mecanismo para prevenir que, como @rnrneverdies menciona, esto se vuelva en una carrera de "a ver quien la traduce mas rápido" y al final los usuarios con mas reputación sean los solo los traductores mas veloces, quienes podría llegar a ser, ni siquiera tienen una idea del tema que tradujeron.

Answer (score 1):

Si y deberia incluirse referencia a la pregunta original

Answer (score 1):

Coincido con varias de las respuestas en las que indican que sí es válido pero en particular con la que indica que debería evitarse hacerse esto durante la beta privada.

Considero que deberíamos utilizar una etiqueta especial para identificar las preguntas que su intención original fue realizar la traducción de la pregunta/respuesta de otro sitio. Uno de los beneficios de esto es que las medallas de bronce, plata y oro asociadas a esta etiqueta nos podrían dar luz de que cuáles usuarios tienen vocación de traductores.

Answer (score -4):

### No son nada aceptables, por dos motivos

1. Lo que se volvió es **una carrera de ganar puntos**, que fácil es tomar preguntas/respuestas populares para ganar **puntos**/privilegios/**popularidad** por montón a costa del trabajo de otros (los que hicieron la preguntas/respuestas originales) a ver si mejor se gastan ese mismo tiempo con contenido original
2. Es mejor **fomentar el crecimiento orgánico**, cuando surja una pregunta legítima realmente se le estará ayudando a la comunidad y tanto el que pregunta como el que contesta legítimamente tendrá deseos de volver y poner su grano de arena

### Addendum

Deberíamos **marcar todas las traducciones** ya hechas **como Wiki** para que **no sumen puntos a nadie** y adicionalmente de ahora en más no permitir preguntas traducidas del inglés y de la misma forma verificar que las respuestas no terminen siendo lo mismo.

Comment: Como lo manifesté con mi respuesta así como con votos positivos en otras preguntas yo si estoy de acuerdo en que se realicen traducciones, sobre todo ya que la etapa de beta privada ha sido superada. Por otro lado, no estoy de acuerdo que todas las traducciones se marquen como  wiki.

Comment: Bien aunque creo que el tema ya quedo definido por el admin , fue discutido y cerrado en su momento. Busca en meta los temas relacionados

Comment: ¿Admin? ¿Quien es el admin? ¿O te refieres al amo del calabozo :P ?

Comment: Encontré la respuesta de [Juan M](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) -> http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/93/65.