# ¿Son aceptables las traducciones de preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, traducciones-de-contenido

Mi pregunta sigue el mismo hilo que [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl/), realizada por **@Konamiman**, pero en este caso sobre las preguntas:

¿Se adaptaría al código de StackExchange el traer preguntas del sitio en inglés, ya bien sea directamente traducidas, o formuladas de manera similar?

Hablo de preguntas interesantes, relativamente complejas y que aporten algo a la comunidad, intentando excluir aquellas que, pese a que puedan ser muy concurridas, sean demasiado básicas.

Comment: Creo que también es importante mencionar que, en mi opinión, si uno hace una pregunta de este tipo, debería intentar evitar contestarse a sí mismo, para evitar que parezca que busca reputación fácil, y para permitir a otros usuarios aportar su punto de vista.

Comment: Creo que esa era una de las ideas que se planteó en Area 51 cuando se propuso SO en Español. Yo no lo vería mal siempre que se ponga una referencia a la pregunta/respuesta original. Sobre la reputación: si la pregunta se hace community wiki, la persona que pregunta/responde deja de recibir reputación evitando problemas con ese tema.

Comment: No tiene sentido que falte contenido en SO Español que ya exista en SO Ingles.

Comment: @Hewbot, En realidad este comportamiento es avalado en el sitio en tanto en Inglés como en español (http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) para permitir compartir el conocimiento de una persona sobre un tema en específico o sobre un problema que el o ella mismo solucionó. Y si el resto de las personas les parece útil pues sí se merece la reputación.

Comment: Lo que yo agregaría en todo caso es que se debe incluir el link a la pregunta (y posible respuesta) en la traducción para indicar claramente que se trata de una traducción y dar créditar a los autores originales recuerden que el contenido de SO en inglés y español sigue la licencia cc by-sa 3.0  que explicitamnete require esta atribución

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con que se publique una traducción siempre y cuando se haga la correspondiente referencia a la pregunta y respuesta original.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [¿Son aceptables las traducciones directas de respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl)

Comment: Barranka, por favor, lee detenidamente la pregunta. Desde el principio he especificado que trata sobre el mismo asunto, pero desde la perspectiva de las preguntas, en vez de las respuestas.

Comment: @Hewbot Creo que los criterios para traducir una pregunta o una respuesta deben ser los mismos: la publicación (pregunta o respuesta) debe ser lo más comprensible posible. En lo que concierne a las preguntas, creo que hay un paso adicional para considerar: *¿Para qué traducir la pregunta?* Creo yo que vale la pena traducir una pregunta si se incluye también una respuesta (compartiendo el conocimiento). SO en español no se trata de traducir SO en inglés, sino de generar una base de conocimiento sólida en español (con o sin referencias a SO en inglés)

Comment: @Hewbot por cierto, tienes razón... retiré ya mi voto de cierre

Comment: En otra pregunta existen varias razonamientos de algo similar http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/55/152

Comment: No estaria en contra de traducir preguntas mas compljeas, pero no las basicas.

Comment: "Sólo debes hacer preguntas prácticas y solucionables basadas en problemas reales que afrontas.".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tenemos un océano de información disponible en la versión de Stack Overflow en inglés.  Permítanme explicar mis pensamientos sobre la cultura de nuestro sitio y contestar la pregunta sobre las traducciones de preguntas ya existentes en el otro sitio.

### Nuestro sitio es único y será creado por nosotros los usuarios.

Es importante recordar que no queremos un clon del sitio en inglés.  Debemos formar nuestro propio sitio utilizando nuestras experiencias y necesidades.  Claro, algunas cosas serán similares al otro sitio pero, por lo general, buscaremos nuestro propio camino porque nuestra meta es servir a los desarrolladores de habla hispana.

### ¿Se permiten las preguntas/respuestas traducidas del inglés, japonés, ruso, portugués (etc.) al español?

Sí, se permiten siempre y cuando lleven lo siguiente en su contenido:

- Una traducción adecuada y hecha por un ser humano.  Di "No" a los traductores automáticos.
- Un enlace al final dando referencia a la pregunta/respuesta original. Si el enlace no existe, la pregunta/respuesta se borrará. Es muy importante seguir el CC-BY-SA y ser transparentes sobre el hecho de que la pregunta/respuesta es (1) traducida y (2) la aceptada.
- El codigo deberá aparecer al igual que en la pregunta/respuesta original.  No traduzcan el codigo porque eso creara muchos problemas.

### ¿Qué hay de la reputación entonces?

La reputación no mide la inteligencia de un usuario sino el grado de ayuda que este proporcione.  Dicho así, el traducir ciertas preguntas/respuestas merece una recompensa de reputación por el trabajo completado.  El traducir preguntas/respuestas no es cosa fácil.

Nuestro Centro de Ayuda nos indica que:

> Sólo debes hacer preguntas prácticas y solucionables basadas en **problemas reales que afrontas**.

Estos problems reales pueden haber ya sido resueltos on otros sitios de Stack Overflow.  Agregemos los más interesantes solamente.

### ¡Advertencias!

No todas las preguntas/respuestas de los otros sitios de Stack Overflow deben ser traducidas. Debemos evitar traer ese contenido aquí a menos que sea útil para nuestros usuarios.

Por favor utilicen mucha prudencia.  Queremos contenido original y pertinente a nuestras necesidades.  Somos una cultura diferente y por lo mismo nuestro sitio debe reflejar eso.

Comment: Que pasa si la pregunta original es community wiky (como [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-string-y-string)), a mi me parece que seria apropiado respetar los deseos de los autores originales también.

Comment: @Juan M saludos creo que esto de las traducciones se esta saliendo de .... hacia unos dias que no entraba y cuando entre me lleve una buena y una mala sorpresa la buena que habia mucha mas gente y preguntas la mala que muchas de ellas eran preguntadas y respondidas por los mismo que las creaban, y que esto este ocurriendo a estas alturas no se si es lo mejor para el sitio, ademas que creo que a las persona que quieren responder y entran el las preguntas se encuentran con el panorama que ya ha sido respondida por el mismo que la propuso puede llegar a cansar de echo a mi ...

Comment: Esto es extremadamente peligroso. Si, podemos copiar las respuestas, pero ¿deberiamos? Es improbable pensar que no podemos pensar en una pregunta *por nuestra cuenta*, sin necesidad de ir a SO. Se supone que somos profecionales o entusiastas todos.

Comment: @AngelAngel las preguntas que has visto respondidas por los mismos autores me parecen ser las creadas durante la primera version (la version anterior a esta beta).  No te preocupes sobre esas preguntas, con nueva actividad podremos agregar mas variedad a lo que vemos ahora.

Comment: @JuanM no para nada son preguntas de hace dos dias, tu mismo puedes verlo que ami me da igual pero mira las ultimas no se 10, y veras a lo que me refiero, y encima se responde en unos segundo y quizas eso no le agrade a mucha gente por lo menos yo no soy partidario de eso espero me entiedas, y gracias por tu esfuerzo con el sitio

Comment: @JuanM creo que hace falta un pronunciamiento oficial sobre lo que debemos hacer con las nuevas preguntas traducidas que pudieran surgir.

Comment: He traducido la pregunta con más votos en el SO inglés : ¿Por qué se procesa más rápido un array ordenado que uno desordenado? Es mi pregunta/respuesta favorita y creo que es de interés general. He recibido tanto muestras de apoyo como de desaprobación. Traducir una pregunta/respuesta tan larga y compleja, ejecutando yo mismo el código y verificando los resultados para asegurarme de que sigue siendo vigente, lleva mucho tiempo. Unas dos horas me costó. Mi intención es seguir traduciendo, creo que es una aportación útil. Pero no tengo claro cómo manejar el tema, si hacerlas todas wiki o qué.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos conste aquí que te agradezco la traducción, porque no es un trabajo trivial <3

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Tal vez se puede en un futuro hacer todo por wiki (estamos como empresa analizando las posibilidades) pero por ahora, puedes traducir las preguntas que pienses que sean las mas útiles para nuestros miembros.

Comment: Se trata de obtener ventaja por parte de algunos usuarios para lograr puntos en preguntas como esta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/por-qu%C3%A9-se-procesa-m%C3%A1s-r%C3%A1pido-un-array-ordenado-que-uno-desordenado , sin embargo el usuario no tiene ni 5000 puntos en StackOverflow, espero se deje de realizar esto porque si es así, también iniciare al copiado de preguntas.

Comment: `Un enlace al final dando referencia a la pregunta/respuesta original` -- Me gustaría sugerir que ese enlace está pequeño y no intrusivo. He visto muchos que son grandes--a veces más grande que la pregunta!

Comment: Seria calidad una especie de buscador que tradusca las pregunta de un sitio que coincida con la pregunta del usuario actual.

Answer (score 22):

Si una pregunta ya fue hecha en StackOverflow en inglés, o en cualquier otro idioma, una traducción puede ser una buena idea. Sin embargo, valdría la pena preguntarse: *¿Vale la pena hacer una pregunta hecha en otro sitio?* Mi opinión es: sí y sólo sí se va a poner también la respuesta (en el espíritu de "compartir el conocimiento")

Además, creo que es importante considerar lo siguiente:

1. "Honor a quien honor merece": Si se traduce una pregunta o una respuesta de SO (en inglés, en portugués, en ruso, etcétera) y se publica aquí, lo justo es incluir una liga a la publicación original.
2. Las traducciones "directas" o hechas por un servicio automático de traducción *no necesariamente* son comprensibles. Las publicaciones traducidas deben ser consistentes, congruentes y comprensibles, lo que exige que la persona que las escriba sepa (como mínimo) comprender la publicación en español y escribir una pregunta (y respuesta) comprensible en español.
3. Es muy frecuente encontrar términos técnicos que no se pueden o no se deben traducir (por ejemplo, yo sigo batallando para asimilar que "trazador cúbico" es una traducción de "cubic spline"... no sé cuantas personas usen el término en español, pero a mí se me dificulta mucho... prefiero decir "spline cúbico"). Las traducciones publicadas deben ser hechas de forma tal que respeten los términos técnicos o las palabras clave concernientes al problema, en la medida de lo posible o lo prudente.
4. El código *no debe ser traducido a otro idioma* (aún recuerdo aquella rareza de MS Office 95, si no me equivoco, que tenía código en español). No es lo mismo `Public Function` que `Función Pública`

Para concluir esta respuesta, me permito citar una frase del director de cine Zhang Yimou que tiene que ver con las traducciones:

> *"All translations are handicapped. Every word has different meanings in different cultures"* ([Eye Weekly](http://web.archive.org/web/20060521211057/http://www.eye.net/eye/issue/issue_09.30.04/film/mediumcool.html))

Comment: Me gusta mucho como lo planteas, pero entonces, ¿no habría problema alguno en que un usuario se dedicase principalmente a traducir preguntas, en vez de crear contenido original?

Comment: Opino lo mismo, gente puede empezar a traducir y ganar puntos infinitamente.

Comment: Entiendo que si la pregunta fue hecho por uno mismo, no tendría nada de malo recrearla aquí sin necesidad del enlace (igual me parece que deberían ser preguntas no de soluciones algorítmicas específicas si no más bien que les puedan pasar a cualquiera en un determinado momento sobre un determinado tema) *corre a traducir sus preguntas xD.

Comment: Creo que el comentario de Alvaro Montoro puede ser relevante: Si vas a traducir tus preguntas y respuestas de SO, publícalas como Wiki. Particularmente en esta fase de beta privada es importante generar una masa crítica de preguntas y respuestas, pero hay que evitar incentivos perversos. Yo estoy tentado a publicar mis preguntas traducidas aquí, pero no lo he hecho porque no quiero ganar reputación "gratis" (yo creo en el enfoque de StackExchange). Estamos comprometidos con esta propuesta, así que es nuestro deber hacerla funcionar desde hoy de la mejor manera.

Comment: Yo creo que depende de que tan importante sea la pregunta, si alguien se agarra a traducir 100 preguntas en un día y consigue la misma reputación que alguien que traduce una en un día con cientos de votos pues la verdad no le veo problema o ¿Qué piensan?

Comment: Una nota importante en cuanto a las atribuciones: no se trata de "Honor a quien honor merece", la licencia de Stack Overflow es CC BY-SA 3.0 y la atribución es obligatoria.

Comment: A mi modo de ver, la traducción de una pregunta y su respuesta (aceptada) le aportan al objetivo de este sitio (dar acceso a la información de SO a los hispanohablantes) siempre y cuando se respete la atribución del contenido original, como lo dice @astrojuanlu. Como serían traducciones contextualizadas no automatizadas, se garantiza un esfuerzo de parte de quien las traduzca, así la reputación que esa persona gane no sería completamente "gratis" (no es solo copy/paste). Además está la opción de community wiki, para quienes tengan objeción de conciencia sobre ganar reputación con esto.

Comment: Esto debilita todo el propósito y lo lleva a uno a preguntar ¿hay alguien realmente necesitando ayuda aquí? ¿Hay realmente personas que saben acá? ¿O solo traductores? ¿Que es que nosotros no podemos volver a responder las mismas preguntas de forma original y labrarnos una reputación verdadera a partir de ello?

Comment: por mas que traduzcan miles de preguntas y respuestas, no se van a convertir en Jon Skeet. Su reputación va a valer poca cosa para quienes analicen esos perfiles de usuario.

Comment: @rnreverdies La mitad del trabajo es llegar a los reclutadores, y en mi experiencia a la gran mayoría de ellos les importa mucho la reputación y no tanto cómo se obtuvo, por lo que aunque no sean Jon Skeet, esa reputación que ha sido mal premiada termina pareciéndome injusta.

Comment: @ArthurChamz y el proposito de SO es que hayan menos malos programadores, no creo que traduciendo SO sea la manera de lograr este objetivo.

Answer (score 13):

[¿Estamos aqui para traducir SO, o para crear y compartir *nuestro propio conocimiento*?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/70/152) El [centro de ayuda dice bien claro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> Sólo debes hacer preguntas prácticas y solucionables basadas en **problemas reales que afrontas**.

Si simplementes copias las preguntas y respuestas de Stack Overflow, tu no estas creando conocimiento, simplemente copiando de otro lado.

¿Qué puedes hacer entonces? Piensa en un problema reciente que tuviste, o te topaste hablando con otra persona, compañero, etc., haz una pregunta sobre eso, o mejor aún, pregunta sobre dudas que siempre tuvistes pero no supiste formular en otro idioma. Asi se crea conocimiento, y seremos un sitio saludable, no solo un reflejo de Stack Overflow.

Comment: Me parece una excelente forma de pensar. Incluso deberían de deshabilitar la opción de responderse a uno mismo durante la beta privada.

Comment: @Gepser - Estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Poder copiar de un sitio tan rico como SO en Ingles da la posibilidad de  desvirtuar completamente el uso de SO en Español.

Answer (score 9):

Para mí esto va en contra de lo que es mi visión de Stack Overflow.

Esto debilita todo el propósito y lo lleva a uno a preguntar ¿hay alguien realmente necesitando ayuda aquí? ¿Hay realmente personas que saben acá? ¿O solo traductores? ¿Es acaso que nosotros, los hispanohablantes, no podemos volver a responder estas preguntas de forma original cuando honestamente sean planteadas por alguien acá en el sitio? ¿O caso [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) se labró una reputación copiando respuestas de otros? ¿Donde están los Jon Skeets hispanohablantes? ¿O es que no hay?

Para probar mi punto voy a apelar al aspecto moral de esto. ¿Por que creen que una persona iría a Stack Overflow en inglés u otro idioma y copiaría una pregunta y su respectiva respuesta?

No hay nadie en este sitio legítimamente haciendo esa pregunta, ¿verdad?. La persona haciendo la pregunta ya sabe la respuesta, puesto que la puede leer en el idioma extranjero. Sin embargo, él mismo hace la pregunta acá, y el mismo la responde de inmediato con una traducción de otro sitio.

Hay dos posibles razones, es un traductor heroico que quiere un mejor Stack Overflow en Español, o lo más sencillo de creer es que quiere construirse una reputación acá, ahora que está comenzando, por medio de obtener puntos de respuestas históricamente famosas y populares en los otros sitios.

Les apuesto que si la traducción no recibiera reputación, sino solo etiquetas, estaríamos hablando de otra cosa. Tal vez deberían hacer eso por un buen tiempo, hasta haber amasado una buena cantidad de buenos profesionales acá en el sitio.

La motivación de hacerlo nunca obedece al planteamiento de una pregunta original acá en Stack Overflow en Español, y raras veces es la misma persona traduciendo sus mismas preguntas y respuestas y labrándose una reputación acá a partir de su mismo trabajo en otro idioma. Más bien son personas repitiendo preguntas de otras personas que todavía nadie ha preguntado acá y copiando las mejores respuestas.

Podrá ser todo lo legal que ustedes quieran, pero moralmente hablando no me suena correcto. Si alguien hace una pregunta legítima, y alguien acá sabe la respuesta, pues que escriba una respuesta original y creemos un Stack Overflow en Español con una reputación de verdad, y no una copia barata de traducciones de los demás. ¿Para esto hemos esperado tantos años? ¿Para tener una copia barata del Stack Overflow en inglés? Para esa gracia mejor me quedo en el sitio en inglés. Desafortunadamente puede que esto no sea una opción para millones de otros usuarios de verdad acá en SO en Español.

Pienso que Stack Overflow en Español falla en crear un mecanismo para premiar a los traductores desinteresados con algo más que reputación en puntos. Asimismo falla en premiar a los creadores de las preguntas y respuestas originales. Pues aunque el traductor acá incluya un enlace a la página original en otro idioma, no hay garantía de que los usuarios acá irán al sitio extranjero y concederán puntos a la respuesta o pregunta original. Puede que no la puedan siquiera leer al estar en un idioma desconocido o que ni siquiera tengan reputación para eso en el sitio foráneo.

En todo caso, hacer copias/traducciones de las preguntas/respuestas populares de Stack Overflow en Ingles acá solo para ganar reputación me parece inmoral y le resta categoría a este sitio. A decir verdad creo que hasta pone en riesgo la posibilidad de atraer a verdaderos conocedores dispuestos a contribuir. Fallan en su esencia de poner en contacto a las personas que *legítimamente* tienen preguntas con aquellas que *legítimamente* conocen la respuesta.

Por otro lado, ¿para que vamos a peder el tiempo en Stack Overflow en Español, intentando honestamente responder las preguntas de sus usuarios, si estos todo lo que quieren es labrarse una reputación ficticia con traducciones?

La reputación de usuario usualmente se asocia con sus habilidades y su conocimiento, pero ahora la reputación se puede labrar por medio de copiar y traducir el trabajo de los demás. A mí no me parece correcto.

El sitio de Stack Exchange Careers usa la reputación para buscar a los mejores candidatos potenciales y la mayoría de las personas asociaría la reputación de alguien en Stack Overflow en Inglés con sus habilidades y conocimientos, pero ese no sería el caso en Stack Overflow en Español.

A mi parece que esta actitud de estar copiando preguntas y respuestas va a terminar alejando a los que realmente queremos contribuir. En mi caso creo que le voy a dar una semanas antes de regresar, a ver si para entonces ya se le ha pasado el resfriado.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Como comenté en otra respuesta, ¿habrá forma de bloquear las autorespuestas o al menos ponerle un delay al estilo de las recompensas de un par de días? Eso al menos evitaría un poco este fenómeno aunque lo correcto sería que la gente entendiera que eso que hacen va a matar al sitio antes de existir. Quizá poniendo un enlace hacia acá en las preguntas/respuestas que son traducciones se pueda lograr algo. En lo personal no doy up votes a ese tipo de contenido.

Comment: -1: Stack Overflow es un sistema que *siempre* ha dado reputación a los que dedican tiempo. *A qué* dedican su tiempo los usuarios nunca ha sido una fuente de distinciones, más allá de las propias reglas específicas para ganar reputación (+5 por pregunta, +10 por respuesta etc). Si alguien quiere estar todo el día traduciendo igual le contratarán de traductor, y no de programador :)

Comment: @astrojuanlu - No habia necesidad de hacer distinciones porque no habia un lugar de donde copiar todo. Los puntos dan privilegios en el sitio que no deberias tener por simplemente traducir.

Comment: Edwin, estoy totalmente de acuerdo, por eso propuse esto [paremos el acaparamiento de puntos](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103/paremos-el-acaparamiento-de-puntos?noredirect=1#comment214_114)

Answer (score 8):

Otras comunidades ya tienen experiencia con esto: [Stack Overflow en ruso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Stack Overflow en portugués](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), y [Stack Overflow en japonés](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/). Nosotros podemos tomar decisiones diferentes que las de ellos, por supuesto, pero yo creo que sus experiencias tienen valor para nosotros, y por eso quiero compartirlas con ustedes. Contesto a esta pregunta con una traducción de [esta respuesta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/71/176684) a [la misma pregunta en Stack Overflow en ruso](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/70/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-so):

> La misión de Stack Overflow es la organización del conocimiento. Las reglas dicen claramente que formular una pregunta y responder a ella inmediatamente es normal y totalmente aceptable. Se otorga [una medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) incluso para esto. Se dice que si tú crees que tu información será útil para otros, entonces es tu deber sagrado compartirlo.
>
> Hay disputas sobre los objetivos de Stack Overflow en diferentes  idiomas, pero por último todos tienen la misma idea: proveer información. Si alguien no sabe inglés (o no lo sabe muy bien), es mejor tener Stack Overflow en ruso, incluso con las consecuencias como la fragmentación de la audiencia, que no tener nada.
>
> La traducción de preguntas importantes y útiles, claro, se alinea con la misión de proveer información. Algún día las preguntas se formarán un río, y más programadores se unirán con nosotros, y ya no necesitaremos traducir contenido. Pero hasta que llegue ese día podemos traducir un poco.
>
> Debo añadir, que incluso cuando tú contestas a una pregunta naturalmente, tal vez buscas por Google, y encuentras que has escrito lo mismo que ya hay en Stack Overflow en inglés. Así se puede hacer una "traducción".
>
> Con respecto a la licencia todo es claro: si la fuente del contenido original es indicado, se puede traer información entre los sitios libremente.
>
> Por mi parte, tengo planes de traducir algunas preguntas "canónicas" desde el Stack Overflow grande que tiene conocimiento fundacional: algunas preguntas repetitivas vienen continuamente, y muchas veces es mejor enviar enlaces a una respuesta completa con muchos detalles, y no volver a escribir lo mismo para cada usuario. Por lo tanto, traduje la pregunta y respuesta ["¿Qué significa NullReferenceException, y como puedo corregir mi código?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413041/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-nullreferenceexception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), por ejemplo.
>
> Si tienes miedo que otros te van a culpar por "robar" la reputación, puedes marcar tus respuestas como "wiki de comunidad". Pero eso es un miedo infundado: las traducciones, especialmente las traducciones de calidad, son mucho trabajo también, y tienes todo el derecho a un premio correspondiente.

(No hablo español muy bien, lo siento si la calidad de esta traducción es mala)

Comment: Me parece muy valiosa tu aportación. Muchas gracias. Hay que aprender de nuestros "hermanos mayores" en otros idiomas

Comment: Hablas mejor español que muchos que conozco. No puedo editar los "meta" así que te lo dejo de comentario. `consecuencias` en lugar de `consequencias` es el único error de traducción que encontré.

Comment: @Gepser Gracias, acabo de corregir este error.

Answer (score 7):

Concuerdo con lo expuesto por @Edwin en su respuesta. No me queda mas sino agregar que, aunque aprecio que contenido tan valioso como el de StackOverflow en Inglés sea traducido al Español, me parece sencillamente ilógico dar reputación a traductores. Este es un sitio de práctica y conocimientos de **programación**, no de conocimientos de traducción del Inglés al Español. Por lo tanto, se debe premiar con reputación única y exclusivamente a aquellos usuarios que demuestren tales conocimientos de programación y hayan compartido sus experiencias, si son de utilidad para la comunidad.

Puedo llegar a entender una copia de una respuesta, si contesta perfectamente una pregunta legítima, pero no comprendo copiar una pregunta deliberadamente.

La única solución que se me ocurre para tener el contenido proveniente de SO es que dichas preguntas y respuestas se manejen como wikis, y esto requiere colaboración de nuestra comunidad para identificar aquellas preguntas que sean traducciones directas. Si una pregunta proviene directamente de SO en Inglés y se responde con la respuesta también proveniente de SO en Inglés, tanto pregunta como respuesta deberían ser wikis.

Si algún usuario desea agregar una pregunta directo de SO en Inglés, el mismo usuario debería cambiar su pregunta a wiki al momento de su publicación.

Comment: pero quien tiene el poder (y el trabajo) de cambiar la categoría de una PyR a wiki. osea, ¿Como se "prueba" que es una traducción?

Comment: No sería posible (ni tendría mucho sentido) clasificar toda similitud como copia. Por ejemplo, [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/cómo-puedo-deshacer-el-último-commit-en-git) es bastante general, y aunque ya existen infinidad de recursos en la red con esta información, no la catalogaría como copia. Sin embargo, tanto la pregunta como la respuesta en [este enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/por-qué-se-procesa-más-rápido-un-array-ordenado-que-uno-desordenado) son evidentes copias, y creo que vale la pena tratar de minimizar estos casos.

Comment: Agrego que si algún usuario desea agregar una pregunta directo de SO en Inglés, el mismo usuario debería cambiar su pregunta a wiki al momento de su publicación.

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Es responsabilidad de la comunidad misma moderar estos casos, como todos los demás. Puede que casos menos obvios como el que menciona @ArthurChamz no se puedan categorizar como traducciones, pero otros como [este otro](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/146/252) son muy simples de ver.

Answer (score 6):

Esta pregunta tiene 2 aristas:

1. ¿Cúal es la filosofía acerca de traducciones?, con una mirada a futuro tratando de establecer la norma.
2. ¿Está bien que estén traduciendo preguntas para buscar reputación?

Del primer punto ya se habló suficiente. Para mí, en los casos en los que son 100% traducción de SO, debería requerirse que sean wikis, e incluso pensaría en generar un nuevo flag (reporte?) para cuando no se cumpla.

Pero me interesa más opinar sobre lo que ya vimos que está pasando:

## ¿Qué se hace con los que están copiando preguntas de SO?

Claramente algunos usuarios están copiando las preguntas más votadas en SO, buscando reputación a futuro. Es obvio, se cubre la base de preguntas de conocimiento general, y listo, dentro de 2 años tenés 50 preguntas con 100 votos cada una sin haber hecho nada más que observar cómo llegan las notificaciones.

En algún punto me molesta, y aparentemente a otros también les está molestando. Quizás por desleal, quizás por egoísta, no sé. Pero... ¿Está tan mal? ¿Tenemos que hacer algo?

Analicemos un poco qué implica:

#### Estamos en beta

La idea del beta es probar el sitio. Bueno, la verdad que lo están probando bastante. Desde ese punto, sirve que posteen. Y están generando contenido que puede atraer a usuarios que vienen de google. Eso está genial y nos beneficia a todos, ¿no?

#### Pero ¿por qué mejor no se dedican a contestar?

Todavía no hay usuarios nuevos entrando a preguntar. Dejemos que se diviertan con algo mientras tanto. Esta es nuestra situación actual:
<sub><kbd>[Métricas al día 0, para el actual hacer click](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810)</kbd></sub>
[image: Métricas Area51]
¡Mejor que crezca rápido!

#### Se van a llevar reputación por traducir, no por contestar

Bueno, al menos algo están haciendo para ganar reputación. Y seguramente sean usuarios que queden atraídos por eso, estando presentes en el día a día. Además, ninguno sabrá estimar bien, pero si son 50 preguntas con 100 votos promedio c/u... Para haber traducido 50 preguntas, ¡No es tanto!

#### Pero así no somos originales

Eso no lo logra un grupo de usuarios. La misma comunidad va marcando el rumbo. Ninguno de nosotros sabe en qué termina. Mi consejo: no busquemos prohibir tanto ahora, en cambio generemos lo que creemos que debería ser. El resto quedará abajo de la alfombra.

#### Entonces, ¿Hacemos algo?

Esto recién empieza y nadie sabe cómo sigue. Algunos se van a aburrir, otros empezarán a contestar más y traducir menos. En mi opinión, dejemos que sigan traduciendo todo lo que quieran, en 1-2 meses vemos.

#### Pero si molesta, ¿por qué dejarlos?

Guste o no, hay un hecho indiscutible atrás de todo esto:
**Es lo mejor para el sitio**

---

En mi opinión, dejen que decante...

Comment: 50*100* (5(pregunta) o 10(respuesta)) = 25000 o 50000

Comment: @ninjalj Era la idea (`5000 * rep`), pero veo que quedó mal redactado. Lo saqué para que no confunda. Gracias!

Comment: El mejor argumento que he visto hasta ahora sobre el tema.

Comment: Esas estadísticas están desfasadas y me parece desleal incluir la captura. Por lo demás, de acuerdo en general.

Comment: @astrojuanlu jaja, claro que están desfasadas, el sólo hecho de que estemos escribiendo esto prueba que no son reales... La idea de esa imagen es decir "Estamos en cero", "Recién comienza"

Comment: _Mi único héroe en este lío_. Mil de acuerdo, Mariano.

Answer (score 3):

Mi punto de vista: depende.

Traducir por traducir, no. "Me aburro, voy a elegir alguna buena pregunta del sitio en inglés y la traduzco" o incluso el bienintencionado "Hay un par de preguntas realmente buenas en el sitio en inglés que serían útiles traducidas" no son buenas ideas (con la excepción de *unos cuantos casos para probar el sitio durante la beta privada*; yo mismo publiqué [la traducción de una de mis propias preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/la-creaci%C3%B3n-manual-de-un-alias-de-ruta-con-un-directrouteprovider-personalizado) cuando el sitio estaba completamente vacío). Deberíamos crear nuestro propio contenido.

Ahora bien, si una persona *realmente* tiene un problema y descubre que una pregunta ya existente del sitio en inglés ya lo plantea (o plantea otro problema muy parecido) y o no tiene respuesta o las respuestas existentes no le convencen, entonces no veo nada malo en que se traduzca directamente la pregunta a este sitio.

En cualquier caso, no lo veo un gran problema *durante la beta* siempre que se cite la fuente original en todos los casos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo opino que traducir **preguntas** se debe permitir **siempre**, en el caso de las **respuestas** a esas mismas preguntas, solo **temporalmente**, y a lo mucho mientras dure la beta, debido a que indirectamente ocultan la preguntas sin responder.

La forma más altruista sería traducir solamente la pregunta y esperar a que la misma comunidad la conteste.

Answer (score 2):

Mi opinión:

### Respuestas

Las respuestas traducida de StackOverflow (o cualquier otro sitio) son **más que bienvenidas!**  Traducir los recursos solo disponible en inglés puede ser una cosa muy valiosa a los programadores que hablan Español.

Siempre es buena idea incluir un enlace al recurso original, y cuando tu respuesta es una traducción directa, siempre es mejor marcarlo así, con markup de citación

> así...

etc.

### Preguntas

Las preguntas traducida valen mucho menos, y me parecen un intento de "reputation farming."

Será mucho mejor preguntar *lo que quieres saber*.  Si, de hecho, quieres preguntar algo que ya existe en inglés, está bien preguntarlo aquí también en español.  (Especialmente si no entiendes la respuesta en inglés.)  Una tema central de StackExchange es que las preguntas deberían ser relevantes a tu vida!  Así, preguntar "[¿Cuál es la diferencia entre String y string?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/145/22)" o "la diferencia entre [Puntero vs. Referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/464/22)" no me parecen genuino.  También son las preguntas **más simples**, y así deberíamos no concentrarnos en ese tipo de pregunta, si queremso atraer los expertos.  *Creeme, los principiantes llegarán si nos concentremos en las preguntas de nivel experto, y tendremos todo el tiempo del mundo de responder a las preguntas de los principiantes.*

*Pero si concentremos en las preguntas de los principiante ahora, nunca vamos a tener los expertos, y no vamos a tener tiempo después para hacer nada.*

Si de verdad tienes alguna pregunta así, hazlo... y puedes referir a los recursos en inglés, pero copiar todas las preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés aquí hace *mucho* ruido, y de muy baja calidad. Y si recibes muchas votos negativos, supongo es por eso.

Answer (score 1):

### Cuál es el problema con las traducciones?

En mi opinión, creo el problema no son las traducciones, sino el hecho de recibir un gran incremento de reputación a través de las mismas. Es muy fácil copiar/pegar/traducir una pregunta de SO y ganar 100 puntos en un instante. Por ejemplo, esta traducción ya generó mas de 200 puntos:

[¿Por qué se procesa más rápido un array ordenado que uno desordenado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146/por-qu%C3%A9-se-procesa-m%C3%A1s-r%C3%A1pido-un-array-ordenado-que-uno-desordenado)

### Son útiles las traducciones?

Por supuesto que las traducciones son útiles, siempre y cuando sean correctas como la que mencioné anteriormente. Creo que es excelente tener ese contenido traducido al español, y también fomentaría que la gente sea proactiva con este comportamiento.

### Debería recompensarse a los traductores? Con medallas o reputación?

Estoy **100%** de acuerdo con la recompensa a los traductores, pero en mi opinión dichas recompensas deberían ser medallas de oro, plata o bronce dependiendo de la cantidad de traducciones, visitas de usuarios, favoritos, aporte a la comunidad, otro tipo de medalla, etc. etc. etc...

En mi opinión, creo que la recompensa a una traducción debería ser diferente al incremento de reputación.

Tal vez podríamos tener una bandera para votar cuando una pregunta es una traducción y de esta forma crearla como Wiki de SO en Español.

Qué opinan al respecto?

Answer (score 1):

### **Cual es el propósito de traer preguntas famosas de SO en inglés a SO en español?**

es mejor dejar que naturalmente estas preguntas ocurran.

Lo que vengo yo viendo es personas colocando preguntas famosas de SO en ingles y otras tantas - a veces la misma- copiando la misma respuesta de ingles traducida a español? qué ganamos con eso **aparte de que estas personas comiencen a ganar montones de puntos** por hacer / contestar preguntas que ya son "famosas" y de seguro lo serán ahora de nuevo?

**Creo que debemos ponerle freno a eso**.

### Cuál es nuestra propuesta de valor

cuando los aportes más relevantes que empiezan a fluir solo consisten en copiar lo que ya se hizo en inglés? esa misma tarea la puede hacer cualquier usuario que busque respuestas por medio del traductor de Google o el de Bing.

En mi opinión permitir que eso siga ocurriendo solo nos volverá una mala copia del SO en inglés.

### Así no se forma comunidad

si el sentido de esta nueva comunidad es copiar todos los top post 'gringos' todo este esfuerzo no tiene sentido.

**De mi parte pido mayor intervención y de hecho revisar los que ya se crearon para evitar tener 'premios' por simplemente copiar.**