# Paremos el acaparamiento de Puntos

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Primero, quiero aclarar que este no es un ataque a ningun usuario en particular. El sitio recien empieza y se van descubriendo problemas, y hacemos lo que podemos para mejorarlo. Mi intencion no es empezar una caceria de brujas diciendo que un usuario u otro usuario hizo esto o aquello, por eso no voy a poner ejemplos concretos.

**[Despues de buscar más informácion en Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270226/in-private-beta-are-we-supposed-to-use-the-site-as-a-normal-site-or-the-focus-is) vengo aquí para que planteemos una forma de trabajar enfocada en mejorar la calidad del sitio y en detener lo que parecen ser técnicas enfocadas en acaparar puntos.**

Nosotros tenemos que hacer que el sitio tenga contenido de calidad, y que crezca de forma organica. Tenemos que dar el ejemplo posteando buenas preguntas, con las palabras correctas.

No podemos postear, ni dejar abiertas preguntas que normalmente deberian ser cerradas como "se basa principalmente en opiniones", u otras razones.

Estoy viendo:

- Preguntas auto respondidas, por personas que casi parecian expertas en el tema que preguntaron => eso no es crecimiento organico.
- Varias preguntas hechas digamos por el usuario A y luego respondidas, por otro usuario (digamos B) que parecen estar en equipo. Muchas de las cuales son preguntas basicas, con respuestas que son traducidas (a veces mal) de SO.
- Muchas preguntas básicas => Eso tampoco es crecimiento organico. Y si ademas se supone que este es un site de expertos, no deberiamos empezar por ahi.
- Preguntas que estan mal redactadas y en SO serian cerradas o cuestionadas.

**Me parece loable que haya gente que este dispuesta a traducir preguntas de SO, pero si vamos a hacer eso:**

- Enfoquemonos en preguntas más complejas
- Marquemos la pregunta y o respuesta como "Comunidad".
- Traduzcan solo de temas que conozcan. No podemos mal guiar a nuevos usuarios con información con problemas de traducción.

He visto discusiones respecto a que la gente que traduce tambien merece puntos. Si uno quiere ayudar a la comunidad, que se supone es nuestro objetivo, los puntos son irrelevantes.

Ademas, lo mas importante, **los puntos en SO, se refieren al nivel de conocimiento y no al nivel de capacidades de traducción**. Si permitimos que la gente traduzca todo lo que se le cruce y obtenga puntos, nos vamos a ver en la situacion de que un monton de usuarios van a hacer lo mismo, y no necesariamente lo hagan bien, pues su objetivo van a ser los puntos. Y mientras mas gente haya, más dificil va a ser de controlar. Y esos usuarios no necesariamente sean expertos en ningun tema de los que estan posteando.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con la mayoria del texto pero haciendo un inciso en el segundo punto -> Varias preguntas hechas digamos por el usuario A y luego respondidas, por otro usuario (digamos B) que parecen estar en equipo. --- yo no se si esta practica se esta empleando pues no me e fijado pero cabe recalcar que por lo menos las cuarenta o 50 primeras preguntas cuando fueron realizadas y respondidas solo se contaba con pocos usuarias por poner un numero digamos 10 y es muy probable que se diera la situacion que describes, que repito no se si hay "equipos" pero ahi que tener encuenta lo anterior

Comment: quizas podamos coger este post como referencia y agregar mas puntos para que la gente lo tenga en cuenta en el momento de preguntar,

Comment: A mi me gustaria añadir que si alguien quiere agregar un pregunta que esta es SO que no se el, el que la responda, y si en una semana no tiene respuesta pues que la publique no se algo asi ademas de todo lo que se a mensionado sobre Wiki

Comment: Sobre las preguntas autorespondidas véase http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Sobre "los puntos" véase http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Sería interesante averiguar si en los sitios en portugués, japonés y ruso han tenido la misma discusión, y en tal caso cuáles han sido las conclusiones. No para copiarlas ciegamente, pero al menos para tener algo de perspectiva.

Comment: "Nosotros tenemos que hacer que el sitio tenga contenido de calidad, y que crezca de forma organica." [mi punto desde](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55/qu%c3%a9-ocurre-si-alguien-empieza-a-traducir-todas-la-preguntas-y-respuestas-de-sta/70#70) [que se abrió el sitio.](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%c3%a9s/66#66)

Comment: Este no es un duplicado de las otras discusiones en meta sobre traducciones?

Comment: +1 "los puntos en SO, se refieren al nivel de conocimiento y no al nivel de capacidades de traducción" evitemos esto: http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui

Comment: No encuentro evidencia para sustentar la afirmación de los puntos por equipos. Por el reducido número de miembros en la beta privada es prevesible que este comportamiento suceda.

Comment: @Dzyann veo que no has hecho ninguna pregunta y ninguna respuesta en el sitio, pero parece preocuparte mucho lo que hagan los demás. ¿Qué tal si colaboramos de forma un poco más constructiva?

Comment: @AngelAngel, las primeras preguntas son así porque se hicieron cuando terminaban de corregir el sitio, en la fase "Beta superprivada". Poquísima gente tenía (o quiso) invitación, así que es normal. Las hicieron los que se dedicaron a traducir las cadenas que Transifex no había traducido.

Comment: @astrojuanlu - Obtuve acceso ayer, con lo cual no he tenido de agregar preguntas y respuestas, y no voy a ponerme a traducir preguntas ya existentes solo para obtener puntos antes de establecer cuales son las practicas aceptables. Este post tambien es una forma aceptable de participacion. Yo no necesitaria usar SO en Español, puedo usar SO en ingles perfectamente, quiero participar porque quiero que sea una herramienta para los chicos jovenes y todo aquel que no sepa ingles.

Comment: @Rubén - Se que es valido autoresponderte, yo lo he hecho, pero de una forma organica y con cosas que yo se, no yendo al site original y traduciendo sin parar todos los post. Respecto a los puntos el post dice claramente que son indicativo "de que sabes de lo que está hablando" si agarras preguntas y simplemente las traduces, no quiere decir que sepas de lo que estas hablando.

Comment: @AngelAngel - Puede ser el caso, no he querido indigar y publicar nombres porque se que el beta estaba mas limitado antes. Simplemente me llamo la atencion ver ese comportamiento con preguntas basicas o que no eran el area de conocimiento de los que posteaban. Lo que hace que el comportamiento sea extraño.

Comment: @Konamiman - Estoy de acuerdo, pero no se leer ninguno de esos idiomas. Hay alguien aqui que haya participado en esos sitios que nos pueda comentar que paso sobre este tema?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta podría tener un título más "constructivo" o "inclusivo" (tipo "¿Cuál debe ser nuestro foco en la fase beta?") y que merecía la meta tag [meta-tag:destaque].

Comment: @brasofilo - Yo elegi este titulo porque queria enfocarme exactamente en eso. Como mencione no quiero que sea una caseria de brujas, por eso no di ejemplos especificos sino ejemplos generales. Prefiero poner menos palabras en un titulo, con menos conectores, por eso lo escribi asi. Lo podria cambiar, que te parece "¿Como podemos minimizar las tecnicas enfocadas al acaparamiento de puntos?" Que es la etiqueta destaque? no parece tener descripción.

Comment: @Dzyann, si, por tener dudas he calificado mi comentário con un "creo"... a final, estoy de acuerdo en cómo está (me ha gustado mucho tu pregunta en Meta.SE y la respuesta de Monica)... La meta-tag `[featured]` (solo para moderadores y aparece en rojo) produce esto en la página principal: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkbfk.png

Comment: @brasofilo - Ah, jaja, no me di cuenta que destaque se traducia a featured, perdon!

Comment: @brasofilo - Una de las cosas que me preocupa también es que la gente que esta traduciendo preguntas, o poniendo preguntas que se sabe van a tener muchos votos, no pone preguntas que ellos mismos preguntaron en SO, que no son basicas, y que no van a tener tantos puntos. Se hace evidente que el objetivo es obtener mucha reputación mas que lograr un sitio de calidad.

Comment: -1. "los puntos en SO, se refieren al nivel de conocimiento y no al nivel de capacidades de traducción." es incorrecto. Oficialmente: "La Reputación es una medida aproximada de cuanto confía la comunidad en ti; Se consigue convenciendo a tus pares que sabes de qué estás hablando" http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation . Si ves una traducción y está mal hecha dale un -1, si está bien hecha y se nota que sabe de qué habla dale un +1. Para traducir una pregunta técnica no basta con saber inglés; al que traduce sin saber se le nota pronto, cosámoslo a -1. No hace falta más moderación.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos - Uno puede traducir con un nivel basico, y aun asi no sabes realmente de lo que estas hablando. En general la gente no da votos negativos, incluso en los Metas se habla sobre esto, como conseguir que la gente de mas votos negativos. Y es mas complicado cuando hay castellano de diferentes paises, donde las palabras elegidas varian. Como vi por ahi que usan "molde" en vez de "plantilla" de c++, no se si no sabe, o simplemente usan otra palabra en su Pais.

Comment: Una pregunta auto-respondida al instante debería marcarse como parte de la wiki :)

Answer (score 9):

Una conclusión que yo saco es que traducir las respuesta y responderlas por la misma persona **y mas aun cunado esta es respondida en un corto plazo por no decir que es casi al instante de publicar la pregunta**.

No deja que la comunidad se desarrolle, la gente pierde *(o puede perder)* motivacion de ayudar, o eso creo yo ***porque para que vas a mirar una pregunta que ya se contesto y está es una copia respaldada de SO y estó dia tras dia en 90% de los caso*.**

Basandome en un caso que me acaba de suceder hace un dia.

Yo puse una pregunta en `SO`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533474/this-stdfunction-is-similar-to

y la respondieron en el dia, y la misma pregunta en `esSO`,

[¿Es std::function equivalente a un puntero?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/es-stdfunction-equivalente-a-un-puntero)

la pregunta que realice en `esSO` se respondio `como 15 o 30 dias despues` y pienso que eso forja una comunidad, yo podria haber copiado la respuesta de `SO` en el mismo dia pero no creo que eso sea lo mejor para la comunidad.

La respuesta obtenida de un miembro de la comunidad, aporta mucho mas que una *simple traduccion* **aportada por la persona que responde a su propia pregunta con una copia**.*(que muchas veces ni es una pregunta que realmente el tiene)*

Cuando un miembro de la comunidad crea contenido de esta manera aunque se tarde mas es recibir la respuesta, muchas mas personas ganan con ello y no me refiero a los simples puntos por hacer un copy paste.

Por ejemplo se le esta dando la posibilidad de plasmar sus conocimientos al miembro que responde afirmado y compartiendo sus conocimientos, y ser recompensado por ello, motivandolo a seguir ayudando. Por otro lado aporta a la persona que recibe la respuesta pues puede pensar: **joder aqui ahi gente que realmente sabe** y creo que eso es mejor a la hora de forjar la comunidad porque puedes contar con gente que realmente sabe.

> Si alguien quiere agregar un pregunta que esta es `SO` creo que este
>   no deberia de responderla al momento en favor de la comunidad, para
>   asi dar la posibilidad que la comunidad se desarrolle, y si en una
>   semana no tiene respuesta pues que publique el la respuesta y si esta
>   es crear la como wiki.

Comment: +1 Muy buen punto, también he notado que los usuarios que tienen más puntos escriben una pregunta y casi al instante la respuesta por ellos mismos, si se continua realizando esto creo que todos perderemos.

Comment: StackOverflow tiene [un filtro](http://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) para encontrar preguntas que no fueron respondidas. Si las traducciones son malas, corrijámoslas/mejorémoslas/downvoteémoslas. Pero si son buenas traducciones, **valoremos que hay gente que ahora puede aprender lo que nosotros veníamos aprendiendo desde antes**.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia este debate ya se discutió en extensión y se tomaron decisiones definitivas al respecto, te recomiendo que busques temas mas nuevos en el meta, este hilo esta desactualizado frente a la discusión.

Answer (score 9):

Yo estoy **totalmente** en contra de los *acaparadores de puntos*, y al mismo tiempo [a favor de no hacer nada contra eso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/97/127).

Mi visión es mucho más sencilla:

- Si la publicación no es útil, voto negativo.
- Si te interesa que no sea el centro de lo que está pasando en el beta, asegurate de llenarlo con contenido interesante, buenas preguntas, generar acción positiva, que se construya una buena comunidad... el resto va a pasar desapercibido.

Answer (score 5):

Ganar puntos es uno de los elementos fundamentales de esta plataforma. Hay otros elementos? Si, e igualmente importantes, pero que gente experta en ciertos temas se quede adicta al *site* es algo que ha ayudado mucho al crecimiento -y mantenimiento- de la red Stack Exchange.

*¿Hay algo que podamos hacer para detener/disminuir la caza a los puntos?*
Sí no es fraudulenta, no.

*¿Podemos llegar a un acuerdo entre damas y caballeros para remediar eso?*
Si. Aquí en el Meta podemos intercambiar opiniones e intentar influenciar unos a los otros. Pero, por lo que sé, solo una minoría de los usuarios frecuentes aparece por sus respectivos Metas.

Pero, mucho más allá de los puntos, me parece que [la respuesta de Monica Cello a tu pregunta en el Big Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270226/in-private-beta-are-we-supposed-to-use-the-site-as-a-normal-site-or-the-focus-is/270228#270228) demuestra mucha sabiduría y me gustaría (mal) traducirla aquí:

> La intención de un beta privado es construir un site que pueda ser abierto al público, lo que significa:
>
> - Un conjunto de preguntas y respuestas *del tipo que te gustaría ver en el site*. No lo llenes con preguntas básicas; estás construyendo un site para expertos. Pero intenta hacer preguntas que los usuarios del beta privado puedan responder; nadie quiere ver "0 respuestas" llenando la página principal.
> - Una comunidad de personas parecidas a las que te gustaría atraer durante el beta público. Sí tu site está orientado a los expertos (lo que la mayoría de los sites intenta ser), pregunta *y responde* temas para expertos. Interactúa con otros usuarios del site; no vayas respondiendote a ti mismo todo el rato. Es una comunidad, no un blog, aunque responder-a-uno-mismo es parte de un conjunto sano.
>
> Hay que concentrarse en preguntas reales que todos ustedes tienen. No intenten cubrir todos los temas básicos sí no son iniciantes; en algún momento llegarán los verdaderos iniciantes y les harán esas preguntas, pero de una manera que de verdad ayuda a iniciantes. Dejen que el site crezca organicamente; no intenten cubrir todas los temas básicos antes mismo que la gente sepa que ustedes existen.

Creo que todo lo que ha dicho Monica **ya está escrito** en nuestro guia para orientar nuestras preguntas iniciales:

> #### [Cómo preguntar en la versión beta privada - Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?)

Comment: Si, es por la respuesta de Monica principalmente que mencione, si vamos a traducir, al menos no traduzcamos preguntas básicas, Los expertos no se van a enganchar si en vez de poder responder con su conocimiento hay un ejercito de traductores. Los puntos que se pueden conseguir por otras cosas que no son responder preguntas son minimos y por ejemplo cuando llegas a cierto nivel dejas de ganar puntos por editar preguntas. Si en la Beta privada nos ponemos de acuerdo, podriamos traducir marcando como comunidad, y de esa forma estariamos dando el ejemplo a los futuros usuarios.

Comment: O entonces, sí es un comportamiento serial de algunos usuarios, reportar al CM y pedir que lo convierta en wiki...  pero aquí hace falta saber que opina nuestro CM...

Answer (score 3):

## Respuesta corta

Coincido con varios de los enunciados de la pregunta y con el interés de procurar aprovechar la fase beta privada para construir el mejor sitio posible en español para atraer expertos en programación. No concido con el discurso de la pregunta pero me parece importante porque trata de una primera impresión de la beta privada a la que debería prestarse atención.

Me quedo con la propuesta de que **las traducciones se marquen como wiki de comunidad**.

## Respuesta larga

### De acuerdo

Por ejemplo coincido con:

> Nosotros tenemos que hacer que el sitio tenga contenido de calidad, y
>   que crezca de forma organica. Tenemos que dar el ejemplo posteando
>   buenas preguntas, con las palabras correctas.

...

> No podemos postear, ni dejar abiertas preguntas que normalmente
>   deberian ser cerradas como "se basa principalmente en opiniones", u
>   otras razones.

...

> - Preguntas que estan mal redactadas y en SO serian cerradas o cuestionadas.
>
> Enfoquemonos en preguntas más complejas

...

> Traduzcan solo de temas que conozcan. No podemos mal guiar a nuevos
>   usuarios con información con problemas de traducción.

...

### En desacuerdo

Sobre lo que has visto, no tengo objeción pues es algo propio y en muchas ocasiones imposible de contradecir  ya que las percepciones son individuales, pero no estoy de acuerdo con varios de los juicios que nos compartes:

> - Preguntas auto respondidas, por personas que casi parecian (sic) expertas en el tema que preguntaron => eso no es crecimiento organico
>     (sic).

Esto es fomentado en la ayuda del sitio, véase es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.  Si la pregunta es útil desde el punto de vista de un programador experto, suficientemente bien redactada, lo que procede es darle un voto positivo.

> - Varias preguntas hechas digamos por el usuario A y luego respondidas, por otro usuario (digamos B) que parecen estar en equipo.
>     Muchas de las cuales son preguntas basicas (sic), con respuestas que
>     son traducidas (a veces mal) de SO.

El que los usuarios parezcan estar en equipo podría ser un prejucio. Como otros han comentado, hay varias circunstancias que favorecen que las preguntas tengan respuesta pronto y que sean pocos los usuarios que han respondido al momento.

> - Muchas preguntas básicas => Eso tampoco es crecimiento organico(sic). Y si ademas(sic) se supone que este es un site de expertos, no deberiamos(sic)
>     empezar por ahi.

Si las preguntas son básicas, lo pertinente es agregar un comentario a la propia pregunta señalandolo y mejor aún si se indica el motivo por el cual no es apropiado publicar preguntas básicas durante la beta privada.

> Ademas, lo mas importante, los puntos en SO, se refieren al nivel de
>   conocimiento y no al nivel de capacidades de traducción. Si permitimos
>   que la gente traduzca todo lo que se le cruce y obtenga puntos, nos
>   vamos a ver en la situacion(sic) de que un monton(sic) de usuarios van a hacer
>   lo mismo, y no necesariamente lo hagan bien, pues su objetivo van a
>   ser los puntos. Y mientras mas gente haya, más dificil va a ser de
>   controlar. Y esos usuarios no necesariamente sean expertos en ningun
>   tema de los que estan posteando.

Sobre "los puntos" véase https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation y la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/93/65) de [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m)

Comment: No puse ejemplos concretos de personas, porque no queria iniciar una caseria de brujas por cosas que podrian ser simplemente percepciones. Pero el hecho esta que seria muy posible en este contexto crear un equipo y postear uno la pregunta y el otro la respuesta sin parar.

Comment: Respecto a postear y autoresponder, las guias dicen que se puede hacer, pero la guia esta enfocada en un sitio ya maduro. El nuestro recien empieza, si posteas las cosas basicas, no le des oportunidad a la gente que solo tiene conocomientos basicos de participar. Queremos un sitio de expertos, enfoquemonos en cosas de nivel mas avanzado. Las preguntas basicas ya van a ser posteadas.

Comment: @Dzyann: Me parece que este comentario viene a razón de uno que eliminé porque luego me percaté de la intención que mencionas.

Comment: Respecto a los puntos, el link que pusiste dice claramente: "La reputación es una medida aproximada de cuánto la comunidad confía en ti; se gana convenciendo a tus pares (los otros miembros de es.SOcom) de que sabes de lo que está hablando." Que seas buen traductor no quiere decir que sepas de lo que estas hablando. Puedes tener un nivel muy basico y aun asi traducir. Pero si marcamos las traducciones como wiki, todos estos posibles problemas laterales deberian ser neutralizados.

Comment: @Dzyann: con "Me quedo con la propuesta de que las traducciones se marquen como wiki de comunidad" quise decir que estoy de acuerdo con ese punto en particular :)

Comment: Si me di cuenta por eso puse eso al final de mi comentario :D Es medio complicado escribir algunas cosas claramente con el espacio limitado de los comentarios

Comment: @Dzyann: :D. Anda pues, vamos a construir ese sitio que anhelamos :)

Answer (score 2):

Los puntos de StackExchange son sobre la dedicación que tienes hacia estas comunidades y no sobre el conocimiento sobre diversos temas. Acciónes como preguntar y editar te dan puntos y podrias terminar dentro de los usuarios con mayor reputación sin haber contestado una sola pregunta. Como tal, estos puntos son puntos de reputación y actuan como tal al otorgarte poderes sobre la comunidad.

Aparte de la reputación estan las medallas por acciones especificas y las medallas sobre etiquetas especificas. Las medallas sobre etiquetas especificas sí buscan marcar un conocimiento sobre el tema.

En general creo que traducir una respuesta esta bien, siempre que se atribuya la fuente. Pero se tiene que evitar el traducir una pregunta y su respuesta aceptada de SOen directamentente. Finalmente el objetivo debe ser generar una comunidad positiva de expertos y no simplemente llenar un sitio de contenido.

Comment: No se si esto le parezca a @JuanM pero así es como lo veo.

Comment: Yo no confiaria en un "programador" que "traduce" mejor que lo que programa. Y reputación no es por dedicación tampoco, "La reputación es una medida aproximada de cuánto la comunidad confía en ti; se gana convenciendo a tus pares **de que sabes de lo que está hablando.**"

Comment: Como comentaste, "se gana convenciendo"; Eso no significa que la reputacion busque representar que tanto conoces algo, ni dice que son exactamente los puntos. Lo que sí es "La reputación es una medida aproximada de cuánto la comunidad confía en ti" y precisamente se gana participando.

Comment: Los puntos no son meramente "derechos para alardear", te dan privilegios, y quien tenga esos privilegios tiene la capacidad de hacer o deshacer el sitio, pueden hacer que el sitio fraquese si tienen privilegios que no saben usar, votando incorrectamente y demás, por eso me parece peligroso que se puedan obtener puntos de una manera tan "artificial". Tenemos la oportunidad de empezar algo maravilloso, hagamos lo bien, no usemos atajos que pueden terminar siendo contraproducentes.

Answer (score 1):

### Esto es una comunidad técnica

Hay que premiar/incentivar a los técnicos, no a los traductores.
Que quieren, montarle competencia a bing o a google? o quieren crear una comunidad donde las personas obtengan ayuda y reconocimiento por sus aportes técnicos?

### Tener como referentes técnicos a personas que ganaron sus puntos **traduciendo** artículos famosos de SO en inglés ?

Mientras que con el mismo tiempo / esfuerzo una persona técnica apenas crea un poco contenido original pero no obtiene ni la décima parte de reconocimiento...

Eso me parece una total **mediocridad**, tratar de arrancar la comunidad con un montón de post traducidos y premiando como referentes a personas "ventajosas" que ganaron sus puntos porque fueron rápidos tomando preguntas populares primero que otros...

No creo que esa sea la comunidad que queremos crear...

Comment: Dice el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que `trabajamos juntos para crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre Stack Overflow en español`. No nos interesa cómo nació la pregunta y la respuesta: nos interesa que quien se haga esa pregunta después, encuentre esa respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo personalmente considero que los puntos están sobrevaluados, al final no son más que un incentivo psicológico que se implementa SO mediante la gamificación para incentivar la participación activa de sus integrantes, y pienso que no debe interesar a otros si hay quienes se quieren llenar de puntos mediante "equipos" o "traducciones", siempre que sus aportes guarden un grado de calidad y sean de ayuda para los usuarios de todos los niveles. A mi no me afecta eso, es más me parece excelente que se llene rápidamente el sitio con esas respuestas que todos tuvimos cuando iniciábamos, de esa manera muchos desarrolladores que apenas inician se verán beneficiados con estos aportes, que para muchos "Seniors" podrán ser irrelevantes, pero que para muchos "Juniors" salvan días, eso en un inicio fue lo que me atrajo a SO.

Por otra parte, considero que personas como @jachguate y todos los que le apostamos desde hace más de dos años a una versión de SO en nuestro idioma, sentíamos que era necesario contar con un espacio de este tipo donde todos los desarrolladores hispanoparlantes pudieran compartir y encontrar conocimiento.

Comment: Sí, y en cuanto a eso es más importante enfocarnos en la comunidad.

Comment: Los puntos no estan sobrevaluados, tienen un significado crucial, _te dan privilegios_, que no deberias tener si no sabes lo que estas haciendo. Ya en SO donde existen tantas preguntas que es casi imposible postear algo basico hay problemas porque hay gente que no sabe lo que hace que revisa las colas y vota mal, o edita mal, o abre preguntas que no deberian ser abiertas. Ese es el problema con obtener muchisimos puntos de una forma un tanto artificial. Y ese tipo de cosas le saca las ganas de participar a gente que sabe mucho. Es un tema comun en Meta.