# No traduzcas preguntas de baja calidad

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Yo sé que [a muchas, les gusta la idea de traducir preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/46/22). Mencioné [mi opinión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/202/22), también, pero aquí quiero destacar una cosa en particular:

Muchas preguntas en SO en inglés **no son buenas preguntas**.  SO en inglés ya tiene muchos años, y originalmente tenía bajos estándares.  Por eso, hay muchas preguntas en SO, y muchas con muchos votos, que, si estuvieran preguntado hoy, serían cerrados inmediatamente.

No queremos esas preguntas aquí en SO en español, tampoco.

Algunos ejemplos (sin intentar de ofender los autores), con mis comentarios

- [¿Cómo me conecto a una Base de Datos MySQL con Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/568/22)

  La pregunta [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) es de 2008. Seguramente, esa pregunta será cerrado inmediatamente in SO en inglés, por falta de investigación, y por falta de mencionar lo que ha intentado.  No hay razón para aceptar una pregunta así en nuestro sitio de 2015.
- [¿Cómo verificar que un archivo exista en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/512/22)

  Parece muy similar a la pregunta arriba. También de 2008, y sin investigación, y sin mencionar lo que ha sido intentado. ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/82831/13860)).
- [¿Cómo puedo tokenizar un string en C ++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/462/22)

  Otro ejemplo de [2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c), y sin investigación y sin mencionar lo que ha sido intentado.

Hay otros ejemplos de preguntas de baja calidad que son menos extremos que estas 3.  Pero eso es suficiente para hacer mi punto:

## No traduzcas tonterías

En StackExchange en general, tenemos el frase "Don't migrate crap" (No migres mierda). Esa tema es muy aplicable aquí también. De hecho, ¡estamos hablando de una forma de migración!  No traduzcas tonterías. Las preguntas arribas son, en mi opinión, tonterías.

Si alguna pregunta no cumple con los estándares de hoy de SO en inglés, *por favor*, no la traduzcas para SO en español.

Como todas las preguntas aceptables, una pregunta buena para traducir debería mencionar, por lo menos:

- Lo que has intentado.
- Tu código (cuando es relevante)
- Debería mostrar investigación

Y si vez alguna pregunta así traducida que no cumple estos estándares, por favor vota según los estándares de la comunidad!  Las preguntas traducidas no son "especiales" que merecen otros estándares de calidad.

Comment: Por cierto: "falta de investigación" no es un motivo de cierre en Stack Overflow. Como mucho es un motivo para votar negativo a la pregunta.

Comment: @Pablo: Cierto es un motivo de cierre en Stack Overflow. Tal vez no tiene ese texto especifico en las razónes de cerrar, pero muchas de las razones son casos especiales de "falta de investigación." (Too broad, es un buen ejemplo).  También  ese texto existe en el texto de votos negativos.

Comment: @No, no lo es, mira este mensaje: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/1073063](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283185/1073063). La primera que citas ciertamente es demasiado amplia (¿se refiere a instalar las librerías, la base de datos, al código de la conexión?), pero lo es independientemente de la "falta de investigación". Las otras dos no tienen ningún problema.

Comment: @Pablo: Tu enlace muestra que "demasiado amplio" no es exactamente igual a "falta de investigación." Pero no muestra que "falta de investigación" no es una razón valida a cerrar una pregunta. Hay muchos casos en que "falta de investigación" es una razón válida para cerrar una pregunta.  O si prefieres pensar en "demasiado amplio," está bien. El resulto es lo mismo.

Comment: Primera línea de la respuesta que he enlazado "I really wish people would get off of this idea that "no documented attempts" means the question automatically must be closed." ¿Cómo puede interpretarse eso de otra forma que "falta de investigación" no es un motivo para cerrar?

Comment: @Flimzy -1, no podría estar mas en desacuerdo contigo. Migrar preguntas comunes para gente que no habla inglés y que estén disponibles para la comunidad? Claro que si, lo importante es el contenido de la respuesta a esas preguntas.

Comment: @Pablo: No dice que "no documented attempts means the question must be closed".  Dice "no documented attempts means the question **automatically** must be closed". Así, es posible que una pregunta con falta de investigación debería ser cerrado por esa razón, pero no siempre.  Tampoco, nunca, como parece que estás diciendo.

Comment: @Flimzy mientras agreguen valor al sitio y en beneficio de la comunidad, claro que si. Pueden cerrarlas como lo han estado haciendo pero considero que deberían estar, aunque sea como referencia. Insisto, no todos hablan inglés.

Comment: @CésarBustíos: Claro que no todos hablan inglés.  Por eso existe ese sítio... y así ellos pueden preguntar las cosas que se importan.  Y entonces podemos responder.  Y hasta entonces (entiendo que ahora mismo tenemos pocas personas que no hablan inglés), es valioso traducir preguntas desde SO en inglés... pero *las preguntas de alta calidad*.

Comment: @Flimzy No veo como tu interpretación tiene ningún sentido si se lee la respuesta. "Demasiado amplia" es sólo para preguntas que son, literamente, demasiado amplias. Si una pregunta tiene "falta de investigación" y **también** es "demasiado amplia", ciérrala por ser demasiado amplia. Si tiene "falta de investigación" y **también** "se basa principalmente en opiniones" ciérrala por basarse en opiniones. Si tiene "falta de investigación" y **también** "no está claro lo que se pregunta" entonces ciérrala por no ser clara. Si sólo tiene "falta de investigación" sin más problemas, no la cierres.

Comment: Por cierto, si estás tan seguro de que en Stack Overflow cerrarían la segunda y la tercera pregunta que citas, te reto a que lo intentes. Verás como no puedes.

Comment: @Flimzy esas preguntas de baja calidad o "tonterías" como las llamas, tienen respuestas de gran calidad, de autores originales muy buenos. Muy aparte de eso, el esfuerzo de algunas personas que se dan el trabajo de traducir deberían tener una recompensa (y no estoy hablando de la reputación)

Comment: @CésarBustíos: Gracias por mencionar el esfuerzo de las personas que se dan el trabajo de traducir.  Sí, eso es muy importante! Y es una gran razón que la comunidad tiene que decidir si quiere esas preguntas traducida. Queremos que esto esfuerzo es utilizada en cosas de valor máximo!

Comment: @Flimzy de acuerdo, se tiene que llegar a una decisión final. En base a esa decisión, se acatará el destino de este problema y su solución definitiva

Comment: Che, creo que 11 de las 70 preguntas de este Meta són relativas a este problema... hablé de una nueva meta-tag en mi respuesta medio en broma, pero mirando con mas atención esto no parece normal :/

Answer (score 2):

### ¿Fiebre del Oro?

Quizá solo será posible conocer la tendencia real cuando pasemos a Beta Público y vengan las hordas de programadores no-iniciados al Stack Overflow. No estoy acompañando en detalle lo que ocurre en el site principal SOes, pero parece que este tema ya casi que merece una meta-tag propia en el Beta Privado: [gold-rush](/questions/tagged/gold-rush)

[image: newscenter.lbl.gov]
<sup>*Mining devastated California's environment in the 1850s; its toxic effects persist.*</sup>

Y va a ser la [hecatombe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecatombe) sí [el site que queremos ser](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) se parece a esto:

### Stack Overflow en Español, Translation Services Inc.

---

Mis sugerencias a los estimados traductores para no caer en una contribución que parezca sufrir de la Fiebre del Oro son:

- asegurarse que son tags que dominas;
- comprobar que el código funciona y está conforme los tiempos actuales;
- asegurarse de traducir los comentarios en el código;
- sí la pregunta no es tuya, ¿se puede mejorar?, p.ej., añadir algo más de contexto al problema;
- ¿participas en SOen?, ¡trae tus mejores contenidos para cá!;
- responder preguntas que no son tuyas.

Answer (score -2):

Si se va a traducir tanto la pregunta como la respuesta, lo importante es la calidad de la respuesta. Si las respuestan son interesantes, siempre se puede adaptar la pregunta para que esté bien formulada.

Si sólo se va a traducir la pregunta, entonces estoy de acuerdo en que se juzgue como si fuera una pregunta nueva, con los criterios actuales.

Comment: Entonces, en tu opinión, está bien hacer preguntas malas, si tienen respuestas buenas? No estoy de acuerdo.

Comment: @Flimzy Las respuestas son lo realmente importante. Las preguntas sólo son una vía para obtener respuestas, no tienen más importancia en sí mismas. No queremos preguntas malas porque en general obtienen respuetas malas. Pero si ya sabemos a priori que la respuesta es buena, el problema desaparece. Y en cualquier caso, sugerí que podemos adaptar la pregunta para hacerla mejor.

Comment: Existen muchas preguntas malas en todo de SO, con respuestas buenas. La mayoría también tienen muchas respuestas malas. El hecho que una respuesta buena existe no es suficiente para mantener la pregunta abierta.  **A veces** es suficiente para no eliminar una pregunta con significado histórico, pero eso es otra cosa que no nos importan, porque hasta ahora, no tenemos preguntas históricas.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Si se va a aportar una pregunta el autor debe hacerlo poniendo lo mejor sí, en una pregunta autorespondida debe poner el mismo empeño y cuidar la calidad tanto en la pregunta como de la respuesta.

Comment: Una pregunta mala, es mala no solo porque el autor no hizo el trabajo que tenia que hacer, o fue poco claro, es mala porque cienta un precedente de que esta bien postear ese tipo de preguntas, y despues empiezan las guerras y discusiones porque la gente dice "por que esta mal esta pregunta, si esta otra se posteo", tenemos que empezar con el mejor sitio que podamos, no con el peor que podamos. Si quieren copiar preguntas de SO, estoy de acuerdo con @Flimzy, al menos copien buenas preguntas. Total van a ganar puntos igual.

Answer (score -4):

### No traduzcas preguntas

si son de baja calidad porque no aportan nada

### No traduzcas preguntas

si son de buena calidad porque entonces tener SO en español no tiene ningún valor agregado

Comment: Hay mucho valor en traducir preguntas de buena calidad -- no son 100% los programadores que leen ingles con un alto nivel de comprensión. Aparte, si alguien busca esas preguntas en español, es mas probable que también encuentren el contenido en nuestro sitio.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky - SE, no abrio SO en español para que sea un compendio de traducciones, sino para que sea un sitio que crezca de forma natural y organica. Lamentablemente mucha gente esta puesta en que quiere traducir para poder conseguir reputacion, por eso nisiquiera estan de acuerdo en aunque sea traducir cosas de buena calidad. Ahora mismo esa gente que no sabe ingles, no tiene donde preguntar, asi que esta mucho peor de lo que va a estar, si este sitio empezara completamente vacio. El poder preguntar es algo muy valioso.