# ¿Cuales son los criterios para que los moderadores cambien preguntas a community wiki?

Tags: discusión, wiki-de-comunidad

Una [pregunta con respuesta que he traducido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1402/en-java-los-argumentos-se-pasan-por-valor-o-por-referencia/1403) y que [en origen es community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) ha sido convertida a community wiki por el moderador [Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman). Presumiblemente por iniciativa propia. Con certeza sin mi solicitud.

¿Bajo qué criterios?

Esto tiene el inconveniente de que mi respuesta ha dejado de ser mi respuesta.
Además de ser una traducción de otra en inglés contenía partes que no estaban en el original. Una de ellas es que las referencias son punteros sin aritmética de punteros. Que es algo con lo que se puede o no estar de acuerdo pero que es la forma que yo prefiero para explicar qué son las referencias.

Y las primeras consecuencias negativas ya han acontecido. Ha habido una [edición de mi respuesta que modifica la intención original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/1403/revisions) del autor que soy yo.
Esto no es un error por parte de quien la ha editado. Su acción hubiese sido normal en una community wiki.
En una respuesta que no fuese community wiki probablemente esta persona habría dejado un comentario o añadido una respuesta alternativa o incluso podría haberme dado un -1. Todo ello formas aceptables de comunicar que considera que la respuesta debiera ser diferente. No creo que hubiese editado la respuesta cambiando la intención del autor y si lo hubiese hecho sencillamente habría rechazado la edición.

Concluyo pues que es una decisión desafortunada el convertir esa pregunta y respuesta; especialmente en este caso en que la respuesta parte de una traducción pero ha sido modificada para reflejar lo que yo considero es la mejor forma de responder a esa pregunta.

Pero mi meta-pregunta es general y **abarca también a preguntas y respuestas traducidas sin aportaciones distintas a la traducción**.

JuanM dejó [ya dejó esto claro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/93/301) :

> #### ¿Se permiten las preguntas/respuestas traducidas del inglés,
>   japonés, ruso, portugués (etc) al español?
>
> Si, se permiten
>   siempre y cuando lleven lo siguiente en su contenido:
>
> - Una traducción adecuada y echa por un ser humano. Di "No" a los traductores automáticos.
> - Un enlace al final dando referencia a la pregunta/respuesta original. Si el enlace no existe, la pregunta/respuesta se borrará. Es
>     muy importante seguir el CC-BY-SA y ser transparentes que la
>     pregunta/respuesta es (1) traducida y (2) la aceptada.
> - El codigo deberá aparecer al igual que en la pregunta/respuesta original. No traduzcan el codigo porque eso creara muchos problemas.

Requisitos que he cumplido. Y que si no hubiese cumplido serían en todo caso motivo para cerrarla o editarla no para hacerla community wiki.

Y también JuanM dijo :

> La reputación no mide la inteligencia de un usuario sino el grado de
>   ayuda que este proporcione. Dicho así, el traducir ciertas
>   preguntas/respuestas merece una recompensa de reputación por el
>   trabajo completado. El traducir preguntas/respuestas no es cosa fácil.

Answer (score 7):

No estoy en absoluto en contra de traducir contenido desde el sitio en inglés, simplemente convertí la pregunta a wiki porque la pregunta original ya lo era y consideré que era lo más apropiado. No pensé que ello iba a tener las consecuencias negativas que comentas.

Comentaré el tema con JuanM y/o en el chat de los moderadores para saber cuál es la política en estos casos. Si es apropiado las ediciones que comentas serán revertidas.

**Actualización:**

No he llegado a hablar con nadie, pero después de [documentarme un poco](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) y después [un poco más](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki) (cosa que, lo admito, debería haber hecho antes), he llegado a la conclusión de que esa pregunta, efectivamente, no tiene por qué ser wiki, aunque la original sí lo sea.

He quitado el status de wiki de pregunta y respuesta, y he revertido la edición que desvirtuaba la intención original de la respuesta.

Siento las molestias causadas. Llevo literalmente tres días como moderador, y aún me queda mucho que aprender. :-)

Comment: Gracias por encargarte del tema.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Por favor, lee la actualización a mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, estás haciendo un trabajo fantástico.

Comment: Se supone que las traducciones de Q || A de ingles a español iban a ser marcadas como wiki de acuerdo en una discusión en meta donde hablamos de que haríamos para evitar el gold_mining con Q&A populares de ingles traducidas al español.

Comment: La postura oficial (expresada por el Community Manager JuanM) es "Sí, se permiten", puedes leer su postura con todo el contexto y con las condiciones que deben tener las traducciones de preguntas/respuestas en : http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/93/301. Allí leerás que "el traducir ciertas preguntas/respuestas merece una recompensa de reputación por el trabajo completado. El traducir preguntas/respuestas no es cosa fácil." Y también leerás que hay que hacerlo con discreción(criterio), lo cual, en mi opinión, estoy haciendo.

Answer (score -3):

En cuestión si preguntas algo que ya ha sido publicado en la plataforma pero en otro idioma lo podrían tomar como duplicado y podrían cerrar su pregunta a no ser que reformules un poco la pregunta.

Comment: Esto, no es para nada correcto. Los duplicados son dentro del mismo sitio, no dentro de otro sitio de la red.

Comment: Ademas esta respuesta no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta...