# Etiqueta a la hora de copiar una respuesta de los comentarios

Tags: discusión, respuesta, comentarios, convenciones-sociales

Esta mañana antes de empezar el trabajo dejé un comentario en una pregunta en plan "*Podrías intentar hacer algo como esto*". Al llegar a casa después de trabajar me encontré un mensaje de la persona que escribió la pregunta: "*Eso solucionó el problema, ponlo como respuesta*". Y allá que fui a responder pero, para mi sorpresa, alguien ya había escrito una respuesta que había sido aceptada... Y que era un calco casi palabra por palabra de mi comentario (más un ejemplo).

Supongo que se podría decir aquello de "si te duermes, te comen la merienda" y que me lo merezco por poner un comentario en lugar de una respuesta. Y supongo que no es un plagio en sí, pero es una copia casi literal de mi comentario sin ni siquiera mencionar mi nombre.

¿Existe alguna norma de etiqueta en SO sobre eso? Tanto por parte de la persona que he respondido (¿debería haber mencionado el comentario?¿debería haber esperado a ver si respondía?) como por mi parte (¿le debería dejar un comentario? lo había dejado pero lo borré tras pensarlo un poco).

Por una parte me alegro porque el usuario ha encontrado la respuesta que buscaba, pero por otra parte me da un poco de rabia porque siento que me han "levantado" una respuesta.

Comment: haz probado escribir una respuesta tu tambien? quiza el OP reconoce que fuiste tu el que dio la solución y da por aceptada _tu_ respuesta...

Comment: No creo que merezca la pena. Mi respuesta sería casi igual a la otra y no aportaría nada nuevo.

Comment: Justo me acaba de pasar lo mismo. Dejé un comentario, un rato después el OP confirmó mis sospechas, pero para cuando yo leí eso, ya había una respuesta (ahora aceptada) diciendo lo mismo. Sentí el impulso de comentar "esta respuesta es un robo de mi idea", pero al final, sentí que no vale la pena. Gente así hay en todas partes.

Comment: Relacionado: En el sitio en inglés está el siguiente artículo [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: @Rubén no tenemos la versión traducida? :(

Comment: @rnrneverdies: Estamos en eso.

Comment: @Rubén ¿Hay alguna modo en el que pueda ayudar con las traducciones? Bien traduciendo o revisando

Comment: Escríbele a @JuanM, ya sea que lo menciones en el chat o le mandes un email.

Comment: @rnrneverdies ¡Ya la tenemos! -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @Rubén buenisimo!

Comment: @Rubén por cierto hay un error en el ultimo párrafo del articulo, la ultima sentencia esta repetida en inglés

Comment: @rnrneverdies: Por si acaso lo han pasado por alto, el error fue corregido ayer mismo, luego de que lo mencionaste :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En alguna parte de Meta SO lei que *un comentario no es una respuesta, por ende cualquier persona podria usar el contenido del o los comentarios para armar una respuesta que sea aceptada*. Por mi experiencia en SO y debido a que esa comunindad es **mucho mas agrevisa** en lo que confiere a contestar preguntas para ganar p̶u̶n̶t̶o̶s̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶i̶c̶o̶r̶n̶i̶o̶  reputacion, cualquier comentario tuyo sera utilizado para la respuesta (y beneficio?) de otro usuario y que gane sus puntos. Me ha sucedido muchas veces en el sitio en ingles.

Esta es la comunidad en español, no tiene por que suceder eso. Concuerdo que por lo menos se debe dar atribucion a las ideas expuestas en comentarios, basta con hacer dos cosas:

1. Colocar `<De acuerdo a>/<En base a>/<La idea que tiene> @<usuario>` o algo similar, para atribuir al autor intelectual y evitar el plagio.
2. Si se va a utilizar contenido literal, que al menos se haga la cita correspondiente.

Si el usuario que postea la pregunta no lo hace, sugiero que se edite la publicacion para agregar la cita o, en su defecto, agregar un comentario pidiendo que se cree la cita correspondiente. Los votos a favor o en contra de la respuesta dependeran de cada usuario.

---

Sobre la sensacion de que *te robaron la respuesta*: esto es algo mas personal, y al menos yo lo tomo como explica @Mysticial en [este post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1065197) (traducido):

> Basicamente existen 4 tipos de usuarios en Stack Overflow [y en StackOverflow en Español]:
>
> 1. Los "cuidadores" que quieren mantener el sitio limpio y con buen contenido.
> 2. Los "vampiros de ayuda" que llenan el sitio con preguntas malas/duplicadas que solo quieren que sus preguntas sean respondidas y no les importa el sitio.
> 3. Las "perras de reputacion" que responden todo lo que pueden (o no).
> 4. Aquellos a quienes no les importa.

En estas situaciones, yo lo tomo como 1 y 4: espero que al menos la respuesta sea correcta y realmente no me importa si el otro gano l̶o̶s̶ ̶p̶u̶n̶t̶o̶s̶ ̶d̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶i̶c̶o̶r̶n̶i̶o̶ la reputacion. Al final del dia, se trata de ayudar a la comunidad, y como explico @JuanM en uno de los primeros posts de meta ([enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/93/227)):

> La reputación no mide la inteligencia de un usuario sino el grado de ayuda que este proporcione [a la comunidad]