# Criterios a la hora de responder en los comentarios

Tags: discusión, respuesta, comentarios

Me surge una duda a la hora de contestar preguntas que son bastante simples y se podrían resolver con una línea de código únicamente.

Al ir a añadir un comentario la ventana emergente indica que evites dar respuestas en los comentarios, pero muchas veces he visto que incluso usuarios con bastante reputación dan respuestas cortas y concluyentes en los comentarios.

Siguiendo esta manera de actuar, yo he hecho lo mismo en varias ocasiones, aunque luego veo que al final siempre acaba habiendo usuarios que responden lo mismo en la zona de respuestas, [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300943/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-pasar-de-tener-una-lista-de-solo-n%C3%BAmeros-enteros-a-una-impresi%C3%B3n-de/300944?noredirect=1#comment549874_300944).

Ante esto he optado en alguna ocasión por responder a alguna pregunta que se podría resolver en una sola línea extendiendome un poco, ya sea dando explicaciones detalladas o proponiendo diferentes alternativas:

[Cómo borrar elemento de una lista dentro de diccionario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300932/c%C3%B3mo-borrar-elemento-de-una-lista-dentro-de-diccionario/300935#300935)

[Generar un diccionario a partir de un dataframe Pandas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/293320/generar-un-diccionario-a-partir-de-un-dataframe-pandas/293326#293326)

No sé cual es el criterio si es que lo hay a la hora de dar algún tipo de respuesta en los comentarios en función de su longitud, o si es adecuado poner una respuesta que únicamente contiene una sola línea, o mejor incluir explicaciones, etc.

He leido la pregunta [Etiqueta a la hora de copiar una respuesta de los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412/etiqueta-a-la-hora-de-copiar-una-respuesta-de-los-comentarios), que es la más similar a la mía que he encontrado, pero no resuelve mis dudas, así que agradecería cualquier aclaración. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Esa misma pregunta la hice yo en su día y por entonces un moderador me dijo: *¿Y por qué no escribes una respuesta si tu comentario es una respuesta a la pregunta?* Y entonces pensé: *Pues leches, es cierto*.

Desde entonces, pocas respuestas pongo en comentarios y por vergüenza me explayo un poco en las explicaciones para esconder la línea de código con la teoría que la acompaña.

No sé si será lo mejor, pero si es una respuesta creo que lo correcto es que vaya en su correspondiente categoría.

Comment: Eso mismo había pensado yo, pero como veo que gente con mucha reputación lo hace, me surgían las dudas.

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace A veces pasa que no tengo mucho tiempo libre y veo una pregunta con una solución sencilla, con lo que decido darla en un comentario, porque quiero *desatascar* al OP pero sin dedicarle tiempo. Ya tengo todos los privilegios que se pueden obtener por reputación y si alguien monta una respuesta sobre mi comentario (incluso el propio OP puede), no tengo problema. Pero como dice phpMyGuel, si tenemos una solución al problema, es mejor crear una respuesta directamente.

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Uso el mismo criterio que pablo y que phpmyguel para contestar en comentarios. Desastasco al usuario, pero mejor si alguien puede poner una respuesta completa. Nadie va a criticar una respuesta simple pero completa, que incluya un ejemplo de porque se da el error, la correccion y un link a la documentacion.

Comment: La otra vez vi un tema acá en meta de qué SOE tiene un promedio de respuestas bajo en comparación con otros sitios. Claro, ¡si las respuestas la dan en los comentarios!. Para mejorar esa estadística, una respuesta debe ir en el campo correspondiente, aunque solo sean 3 lineas de texto.

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace en muchas ocasiones el problema en una pregunta es un error tipográfico, en estos casos un comentario es más que necesario para que el OP entienda el error. Después se reporta la publicación por eso mismo, errores tipográficos. También sucede que comento, por ej, _"estás incluyendo la librería X en tu código?"_ y el OP responde _"era eso! gracias"_.

Answer (score 6):

Para mi, el dedicar mi tiempo a escribir una respuesta **es un premio a una buena pregunta** (si, suena *un pelín* pretencioso, lo se).

Si la pregunta es extremadamente simple, o existe mucha documentación sobre el tema (osease, muchas preguntas en SOes, como por ejemplo el uso de cadenas en C), o es consecuencia de un error tipográfico ... pues si lo estimo procedente, voto para cerrarla, y sigo con lo mio.

El responder en un comentario, en mi caso, es un gesto de *cortesía* hacía el OP. Viene a ser algo así como `Te veo perdido. Te echo una mano, pero esfuérzate mas en la próxima`.

¿ Que otros publican respuestas ? Están en su derecho ... y tendrán mi voto si lo estimo conveniente :-)

¿ *Engordar artificialmente* la respuesta ? Opino que **no merece la pena**. Si la pregunta cumple algunos de los criterios expuestos en el 2º párrafo ... poco más se podrá decir que no pueda encontrarse con facilidad. Prefiero dedicarme a tareas mas *placenteras* :-)

Comment: No suena pretencioso, estás usando tu tiempo de manera totalmente voluntaria en ayudar a alguien. Tienes todo el derecho en elegir cómo emplear tu tiempo de la mejor manera, y un comentario constructivo siempre será mejor que nada

Answer (score 1):

En mi humilde opinión si lo que vas a decir responde a la pregunta y puedes escribirlo de forma breve, clara y completa publicalo como respuesta de lo contrario deja un comentario, y como ejemplo, modestia aparte, te dejo esta respuesta.

Comment: Luego si la pregunta lo amerita y te apetece hacerlo, puedes regresar más tarde para mejorar la redacción, extender la respuesta con ejemplos, referencias e incluso explicar casos que aparentemente no son similares con la finalidad de que la respuesta sea canónica.