# He encontrado la solución a mi pregunta en base a un comentario. ¿Cómo marco la respuesta como aceptada?

Tags: soporte, comentarios, respuesta-aceptada

Ayer hice una pregunta que estaba mal planteada y un usuario me puso en un comentario una sugerencia sobre usar una clase en lugar de otra para arreglarlo. He desarrollado esa idea y mi código ya funciona correctamente. ¿Se puede marcar un comentario como respuesta correcta o sería mejor que me respondiese yo mismo en base a ese comentario, poniendo mi desarrollo de código, y auto-marcarme como correcta? Si la solución es esto último, ¿menciono al usuario que me ha ayudado a encontrar la solución como agradecimiento?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Etiqueta a la hora de copiar una respuesta de los comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412/etiqueta-a-la-hora-de-copiar-una-respuesta-de-los-comentarios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay un protocolo para esto:

En el mismo hilo de comentarios, etiqueta al usuario y agradece su respuesta invitándolo a copiar su párrafo como una respuesta para que le puedan dar puntos (incluso puedes darle las indicaciones de cómo hacerlo si notas que es nuevo usuario). En este mismo agradecimiento puedes avisar que, si el usuario no copia el párrafo en un plazo de X días, simplemente vas a "autoresponderte" citando al usuario (con la finalidad que la Comunidad pueda ver y votar la respuesta).

Comment: muy de acuerdo con esta respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

Autoresponderte es la forma correcta!!!

En este sitio, apuntamos a que cada uno crezca. Y responderse a uno mismo es algo que alentamos siempre que otra persona no lo haga o si solo nos dieron tips para llegar a la respuesta!!

asi que si, respondete, espera 1 dia para aceptar tu respuesta, y si queres agradecer a quien te dio el tip en la respuesta, esta perfecto!!!

Tene en cuenta de que tu respuesta sea completa, explique tu problema, la solucion y el codigo necesario para resolver el problema.