# Últimas estadisticas del sitio antes de la graduación

Tags: discusión, graduación, estadísticas

Esta publicación la hago solo por la emoción de haber sido lanzados como sitio oficial.

Como dice [@Mariano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano) pensar que iniciamos desde cero.

[image: Inicio SOes, todo en 0 al 1/12/15]

Aquí comparto una captura de las estadísticas del sitio en Área 51 del 15 de mayo.

[image: Beta Publica]

Y la captura del lanzamiento del sitio [al día de hoy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), ya invariable:

[image: Sitio Lanzado]

Da gusto ver como crece la comunidad :).

Comment: Y pensar que partimos de **[cero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWcda.png)** (la imagen la había publicado en [este post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%C3%A9s/97#97))

Comment: [Anuncio](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/17/stack-overflow-en-espanol-se-gradua-hoy/) en el blog

Comment: @Rubén en razón de que se va a cerrar esa pagina, me pareció buena idea tener un recorderis de las estadísticas con las que el sitio se gradúa, :)

Comment: Si no digo que tu publicación no es interesante, sólo pongo a la mano el enlace al "otro" anuncio. P.D. La páginas en Area 51 no se cierran cuando se gradúa un sitio, de hecho en [Launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) podemos ver a todos los graduados.

Comment: En Weyback time machine tienen una captura con 93 días en beta: https://web.archive.org/web/20160304171503/http://area51.stackexchange.com:80/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Comment: @toledano oh salgo yo XD, ya hace mucho de los dias cuando podia participar mas en el sitio,