# ¿Y si incluimos una pregunta/respuesta canónica sobre NullReferenceException en .Net?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-canónica

En el sitio internacional de StackOverflow, todas las preguntas sobre esta excepción (`NullReferenceException`) se marcan como duplicado y se derivan a una respuesta genérica sobre como resolver este tipo de excepciones. En mi opinión es una buena politica en general, ya que esta excepción salvo caso excepcionales es muy sencilla de resolver siguiendo unos pasos básicos.

¿Sería interesante incluir una respuesta genérica (traducida de la respuesta en inglós o nueva) como en el sitio internacional y derivar este tipo de preguntas a ella?

[Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75879/15301) de pregunta.

Comment: ¡Gran trabajo! Probablemente los _edit_ se podrían mover a una respuesta, pues al fin y al cabo estás respondiendo tu propia propuesta ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí. Esta práctica es recomendable. Si va a ser una traducción del sitio en inglés, considera las recomendaciones brindadas en meta: [¿Son aceptables las traducciones de preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/46/227)

Comment: Gracias por el enlace. A mi no me importa realizar la tradución, aunque mi idea era mas bien que quizá apareciera como "Community wiki" o algo asi, de tal manera que a) no sea una cuestión de reputación para mi y b) cualquiera pueda aportar a la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Ya que la respuesta a mi sugerencia parece haber sido positiva, he realizado una pregunta y la traducción de la primera respuesta [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/15301). Como vereis la respuesta es muy extensa y es muy probable que haya cometido errores en la traducción.Todos sois bienvenidos a criticar/modificar/sugerir cualquier cosa sobre ella.

Además está marcada como *Wiki de comunidad*, con lo que cualquiera puede aportar lo que crea necesario.

---

He traducido la segunda respuesta que se encuentra en la pregunta canónica de Stack Overflow y que tiene como objetivo explicar la excepción para programadores en *VB.Net*. Es aún mas extensa que la primera, por lo que es mucho mas probable que haya cometido errores. Si queréis echarle un vistazo, está [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76862/15301).