# ¿Qué pensáis sobre dividir una respuesta canónica en dos dependiendo del lenguaje?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-canónica

A raiz de [¿Y si incluimos una pregunta/respuesta canónica sobre NullReferenceException en .Net?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2132/15301) he traducido dos respuestas canónicas de Stack Overflow para explicar qué es una `NullReferenceException`. Una de las respuestas se refiere a C# y la otra a VB.net.

@fedorqui ha propuesto que quizá sea mejor tener dos preguntas cada una con su respuesta y su tag correspondiente en lugar de una sola, ya que si se marca una pregunta en VB como duplicado de la respuesta canónica y lo primero que ve es una respuesta muy bien puntuada en C# probablemente no entienda nada.

¿Qué os parece a vosotros?

Comment: Coincidio con @fedorqui considero que deben estar por separado, no mezclar lenguajes ya que puede llegar a causar confusiones.

Comment: Esta pregunta __en particular__, si.

Answer (score 2):

El concepto de NullReferenceException existe en muchos lenguajes con otros nombres.

- C#
- VB
- Java
- Scala
- Python
- Javascript
- Y muchos otros, así como otros nuevos en el futuro.

Y el concepto es el mismo en todos estos lenguajes. Este conocimiento independiente del lenguaje es muy útil. Conviene pues una pregunta independiente del lenguaje con respuestas independientes del lenguaje y no varias respuestas para cada lenguaje en la misma pregunta.

Las respuestas para cada lenguaje también son útiles. Hay diferencias y detalles que pueden ser importantes. Por lo que cada lenguaje merece una pregunta individual al respecto. Y son estas las preguntas que habrían de servir para marcar duplicados pues son las que tienen respuestas ajustadas a cada lenguaje.

A lo que no le veo mucho sentido es a tener una pregunta semigenérica para C# y VB, aunque compartan uso de .Net . Como lenguajes son tan distintos como C# y Java (o más).

Answer (score 1):

Tras los comentarios y votos he dividido la pregunta en dos, que son las siguientes:

- [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75999/15301) (C#)
- [NullReferenceException:¿Qué es y cómo puedo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/76861/15301) (VB.Net)

En cuanto a lo que plantea Jose Antonio Dura, no tengo muy clara mi opinión. Por un lado, efectivamente se trata de una excepción común a muchos lenguajes de programación, pero no se si una pregunta genérica que explique las bases de dicha excepción sin entrar en las particularidades de cada lenguaje encaja exactamente en la filosofía de este sitio.

Si se quiere información genérica sobre programación existen numerosos recursos donde informarse. Por otro lado,desconozco si existe un tag en el que una pregunta tan amplia pueda encajar (programacion-generica?). Además, es posible que esto provoque otro tipo de preguntas demasiado extensas (por ejemplo, por que no una pregunta sobre que es una excepción para empezar?)

Por otro lado, una pregunta con una respuesta explicando la base y con enlaces a respuestas en los diferentes lenguajes parece util, pero sigo teniendo mis dudas.

---

Un último detalle. Sería interesante crear una etiqueta NullReferenceException?

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de añadir en la de VB.Net una referencia a la de C#. Si no crees que ayuda, deshazla sin dudarlo.

Comment: Me parece perfecto @fedorqui. Además, como ya dije está puesto como _wiki de la comunidad_ precisamente para que todos podamos aportar

Comment: El tag es [tag:lenguaje-agnóstico] . Dado que el objetivo es que no haya preguntas de NullPointerException y marcar como duplicadas las que aparezcan me parece contraproducente una etiqueta NullReferenceException; las etiquetas entiendo que son para cosas que sí queremos.

Comment: No conocía ese tag, gracias. Y coincido contigo en lo de la etiqueta