# ¿Se puede solicitar aquí la escritura de preguntas/respuestas autorespondidas?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-canónica

Hay ciertos tipos de preguntas que se repiten con testaruda insistencia. Creo que *la palma* se la lleva *¿Cómo devolver un valor desde un código asíncrono?*, en JavaScript.

Claro, cada una es un caso concreto en un contexto específico, con un título mas o menos acertado ... y hacen muy difícil que otros usuarios distintos al Autor de la pregunta *acierten* con ella (reconozcámoslo, el buscador del sitio no es precisamente lo mejor del mercado).

¿ Se puede solicitar aquí en *meta* que usuarios versados en el lenguaje/problema concreto publiquen preguntas auto-respondidas sobre temas específicos ?

El objetivo es tener una serie de publicaciones *canónicas* y marcar como *duplicadas* cualquier nueva pregunta sobre el tema y en el lenguaje indicado.

De entrada, pido que, **por favor**, alguien con conocimientos en JavaScript publique una sobre el código asíncrono, y como es o no posible retornar valores desde él. Mi +1 lo tiene **garantizado**.

Comment: Gracias!!!!! Llevo mucho tiempo pensando en la posibilidad de hacerlo. Pero, siempre me ha detenido que sospecho que mientras me autorrespondo mi pregunta va a recoger suficientes -1, como para desanimarme.

Comment: @quevedo Ya hay varias respuestas *canónicas* usadas para eso, marcar nuevas como duplicadas: [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42977/19610). Te recomendaría que indicaras con un comentario en la pregunta que su intención es esa, servir como respuesta única a preguntas comunes.

Comment: El problema de fondo es que muchas preguntas, con respuestas aceptadas, y normalmente no muy bien formuladas son casos particulares de "preguntas no formuladas" o de preguntas que poseen respuestas muy pobres que han sido aceptadas por resolver parcialmente el caso; y ameritan preparar un juego pregunta respuesta que **tenga futuro** en términos pedagógicos. Y, no se ve despejado el camino para proponer tales pares. Por esa razón di +1 y saludé la pregunta que abre la discusión.

Comment: Concuerdo; la formulacion de muchas preguntas es ... *difusa*, y con respuestas ... mejorables. No obstante, usuarios con experiencia no deberan tener problema en marcarlas como duplicadas. Observa que la publicacion de preguntas/respuestas canonicas esta permitida, como muestra el ejemplo que te puse antes. Esta pregunta aqui en *meta* es solo sobre si estaria permitido o no **elegir** temas para esas publicaciones canonicas.

Comment: Ya se ha hecho alguna vez, por ejemplo el gran Pikoh en [¿Y si incluimos una pregunta/respuesta canónica sobre NullReferenceException en .Net?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2132/83). Por tanto, más que preguntar si se puede... hazlo :)

Comment: @quevedo crear preguntas autorespondidas para aumentar el conocimiento del sitio no solo está admitido, sino que es alentado en todos los sitios de la red. Sobre todo si puede servir como respuesta canónica de preguntas que suelen repetirse mucho en el sitio. Te animo a hacerlo si detectas una de esas necesidades.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ¡ *Carajo* ! No la vi. Ya digo que `... el buscador del sitio no es precisamente lo mejor del mercado ...` Elimino esta pregunta entonces.

Comment: @quevedo lo que puedes hacer es redactar la pregunta y la respuesta sin llegar a enviarlas, vas previsualizando o lo que necesites para redactarla bien. Cuando ya lo tengas todo bien redactado lo pegas en el bloc de notas. Después creas una pregunta y rápidamente pegas la pregunta y la respuesta así no das margen a que quede la pregunta sin respuesta.

Comment: No vi el enunciado **elegir tema**. No obstante, merece un punto adicional. Creo que el modelo de asignación de palabras claves no es suficiente como mecanismo para categorizar contenidos, pero no lo cuestiono porque no tengo una propuesta alternativa. Pienso que sería ideal poder vincular los pares pregunta/respuesta y eventualmente las preguntas con una estructura jerárquica de temas (similar a la propuesta por Dewey) para clasificarlos y recuperarlos.

Comment: @ordago **Excelente sugerencia**. Aunque suene tonto, no había tenido en cuenta esa posibilidad.

Comment: @ordago no es necesario hacer lo que dices. Al hacer una pregunta, tienes la posibilidad de añadir la respuesta antes de enviar la pregunta y enviar ambas al mismo tiempo. Hay un checkbox que dice _Responde a tu propia pregunta – comparte tus conocimientos en el estilo de preguntas y respuestas_ Como ya se ha comentado, en SE se alienta añadir preguntas autrespondidas para aumentar el conocimiento

Comment: @Pikoh no me habia fijado en ese check, eso es lógicamente aún mejor que mi ñapa :) Cada día se aprende algo nuevo aquí, muchas gracias.

Comment: @quevedo Fíjate en lo que ha puesto Pikoh, es mejor añternativa que lo del bloc de notas.

Comment: Voto por que se reabra la pregunta para ver si podemos crear una lista de preguntas repetitivas que no cuentan con respuestas de calidad.