# ¿Importar preguntas/respuestas de SO en inglés?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Una manera de poblar SOes con buen material sería *importar* preguntas desde SO en inglés, traduciendolas, como es el caso de [¿Cómo valido si una cadena es vacía en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384337/c%c3%b3mo-valido-si-una-cadena-es-vac%c3%ada-en-python).

Beneficios:

- Material ya está en el formato estándar de Pregunta/Respuesta.
- Material revisado/aprobado.
- Refleja los problemas prácticos de los usuarios del sitio.
- Educa y anticipa los problemas.

¿Qué respaldo hay para esta idea?

Comment: Navegando por la etiqueta [meta-tag:traducciones-de-contenido] verás que ha habido bastante debate al respecto desde hace tiempo. Cuando se abrió este sitio se pidió frenar un poco pues se veía como una manera de conseguir mucha reputación en poco tiempo. Una vez el sitio ha cogido velocidad normal, sin necesidad de aceleraciones, es algo que en general se valora y anima a hacer. De hecho, el CM Nicolas creó un sistema para "asociar" preguntas de SO con SOes para que los visitantes de SO con navegador en español vean referenciada la pregunta en SOes -> [Aquí cómo funciona](/q/3967/).

Comment: Tengo poco que añadir a lo que ha dicho @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'. Sólo, como opinión personal, yo trataría de no abusar de las traducciones. No le veo sentido a traducir preguntas y respuestas con poca repercusión. Si que me parece estupendo que, si alguien hace una pregunta en el sitio que tiene respuesta en el sitio en inglés, en lugar de enlazar a dicha respuesta esta se traduzca (poniendo un enlace a la original siempre).  También recibiría con los brazos abiertos lo que son "respuestas canónicas" para preguntas hechas muy frecuentemente. Todo esto es opinión personal nada mas

Comment: pues muy de acuerdo con lo que comentas, @Pikoh. Tu iniciativa en [¿Y si incluimos una pregunta/respuesta canónica sobre NullReferenceException en .Net?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2132/83) fue muy buena, ojalá haya más pues tengo la sensación de que caemos con demasiada frecuencia en la repetición de respuestas muy similares a problemas parecidos, en lugar de tener una buena pregunta recipiente de duplicados con todos los detalles necesarios.