# Si cambian "be nice", ¿deberíamos tener una discusión respecto al nuevo documento?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, centro-de-ayuda, código-de-conducta

Siguiendo [We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038/141717) en meta, estan teniendo una discusion sobre como escribir el documento. A medida que el documento crezca y vaya madurando, ¿deberíamos tener la misma discusión sobre el mismo en español?

Dado que tradujimos [compórtate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), deberiamos tambien traducir este?

¿O es sólo uno de esos documentos que están solo en inglés?

No parece ser un documento legal, es más que todo una política de conducta. Entonces, para ir despacio pero pensando en esto, ¿debemos tener una discusión sobre cómo escribir el mismo? Sobre todo por frases o cosas que no se entiendan.

Comment: Lo primero sería ponerle los acentos a esta publicación :P

Comment: Para eso esta fedorqui :p

Comment: Aun no leo toda la discusión en cuestión, pero al parecer es muy pronto para saber dónde publicarán el documento y si este será un traducible de la forma que lo hemos hecho con los artículos de ayuda. Tal vez una de las preguntas  a hacer sería si se tiene pensado involucrar a las comunidades internacionales y cómo se haría ello.

Comment: Ese es un trabajo para JuanM!!! ahora le digo a algunos de los chicos que lo contacte... asi nos desasna....

Comment: Estoy viendo el documento que están redactando y me está dando mala espina.

Comment: Viendo la traducción de comportate hay un error en la primera línea. Pone 'Sí haz venido' cuando debería ser 'Sí has venido'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sí, vamos a cambiar lo de Be Nice / [Compórtate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).  Se están aceptando sugerencias ahora en inglés solamente.  Les recomiendo que participen en eso si les interesa.

En cuanto se terminen las nuevas normas de conducta, las podremos traducir.  Por eso es importante el compartir nuestras sugerencias.  Nuestras ideas ayudarán a transformar ese documento (el cual tendrá valor aquí también).

*Para los que necesiten ayuda para traducir sus ideas al inglés, estamos aquí para ayudar.*

Answer (score 6):

Por supuesto que sí deberíamos tener una discusión al respecto. Como [dijo Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/93/301):

> ### Nuestro sitio es único y será creado por nosotros los usuarios.
>
> Es importante recordar que no queremos un clon del sitio en inglés.
> Debemos formar nuestro propio sitio utilizando nuestras experiencias y
> necesidades. Claro, algunas cosas serán similares al otro sitio pero,
> por lo general, buscaremos nuestro propio camino porque nuestra meta
> es servir a los desarrolladores de habla hispana.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Aunque por lo que comenta Juan M en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3563/83) parece que lo que se hará es simplemente traducir lo que se decida en Meta.SE.

Comment: Lo que yo entendí de la respuesta de Juan es que la discusión oficial se está llevando en Meta SE. Nótese que se ofreció a ayudar en traducir las ideas al inglés. Eso (que allá se esté llevando la discusión oficial) no descarta que acá hablemos en español de lo que se está discutiendo allá en inglés.

Comment: @Rubén Es un buen compromiso. En cuanto Juan ponga "We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!" y "our draft" traducidos pondré mis ideas e imagino que no seré el único.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos de la respuesta de Juan entiendo que no se va a traducir el post de meta o el draft, sino que la discusión y las sugerencias se deberían hacer en inglés en el thread de MSE

Comment: @g3rv4 Yo he entendido que Juan M se ha ofrecido a *"Para los que necesiten ayuda para traducir sus ideas al inglés, estamos aquí para ayudar."* Evidentemente el primer paso de esa ayuda es traducir el post de meta y el draf a castellano. En caso contrario alguien que no sepa inglés no puede participar. Esa oferta sin la traducción de post y draft sería una oferta vacía.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta es buena y que este cambio solo concierne al stackoverflow que realmente tiene problemas en las relaciones interpersonales.