# La propuesta del nuevo código de conducta empieza con un problema de congruencia

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, código-de-conducta

## Resumen

El título de la propuesta del nuevo código de conducta no es congruente con su primer párrafo y este a su vez no es congruente con lo que se ha dicho que es dicho documento. Siendo que se está abordando el tema de código de conducta, en mi opinión, debería tenerse sumo cuidado con esto y corregirse **tan pronto como sea posible**.

## Extenso

[We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038/289691) se convoca a la comunidad de la red de Stack Exchange a dar comentarios sobre la propuesta de un nuevo código de conducta para la red de Stack Exchange.

Se menciona

> Is anything in this document, including its purpose, unclear to you in any way? Are there any instances where you'd suggest alternate language or copy? Where? Why?

*traducción*

> ¿Hay cualquier cosa en este documento, incluyendo su propósito, falto de claridad para tí en cualquier forma? ¿Existen cualquier instancia donde sugerirías lenguaje alternativo o copia? ¿Dónde? ¿Por qué?

En [The Stack Exchange Network Code of Conduct (R7)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1BpL_G_m6F5LIPMUZVcLejSPFTb3XbI_69X8fQSZAk/edit)

dice

> Our mission is to build an inclusive community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise, identity, or language. Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

*Traducción rápida*

> Nuestra misión es construir una comunidad inclusiva donde todas las personas se sientan bienvenidas y puedan participar, independientemente de su expertise, identidad o lenguaje. Ya sea que hayas venido a realizar preguntas o a compartir generosamente lo que sabes, únete a nosotros a construir un comunidad de aprendizaje que cimentada en amabilidad, colaboración y respeto mutuo.

En un [comentario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct?page=1&tab=votes#comment1020633_312050) a https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312050/289691 (213 puntos)  Kristina Lustig♦  dice

> I think this is a point of clarification: the team of us working on this stuff's mission is as stated - it's a separate mission from our overall company mission. Having a specific team mission helps us scope and direct our work appropriately.

*Traducción rápida*

> Yo creo que este es un punto de aclaración: nuestro equipo, trabajando en la misión de esta cosa es como se ha dicho, es una misión separada de la misión general de nuestra compañía. El tener una misión específica para el equipo ayuda a enfocar y dirigir nuestro trabajo apropiadamente.

### Opinión

Veo positiva la aclaración de Kristina, sin embargo eso no arregla la propuesta de código de conducta. Además me parece que es muy desafortunada la elección de palabras, en específico "misión". En el ámbito organizacional el concepto de misión es para objetivos de alto nivel no para el de un documento.

Por otro lado empieza con "Nuestra misión", lo cual provoca que no haya congruencia pues un código de conducta es singular, no plural, es una cosa no una persona o grupo de personas.

Otros comentarios similares

- [We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct#comment1020690_312050)
- [We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct#comment1020703_312050)

### Sugerencias

- Modificar la redacción, en concreto en lugar de "Nuestra misión" decir "La misión del equipo a cargo del nuevo código de conducta"
- Agregar la documento una sección que lleve por título *Objetivo* o *Propósito* del Código de Conducta.

### Sobre el sentido de urgencia

El primer párrafo es lo que establece el marco de lo que se va a leer a continuación, establece expectativas e influye en el ánimo del lector. Algunos verán muy por encima lo dicho por Tim Post en la convocatoria y irán directo al documento, y al encontrar esa falta de congruencia posiblemente quedarán confundidos.

### Otras respuestas relacionadas

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312206/289691 (20 puntos)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312383/289691
  Se trata una aportación mía allá en la discusión oficial en inglés. No es una traducción de esta, pero es relacionada ya que tiene que ver con el uso de la primera personal plural y en al cual sugiero usar la tercera persona neutra y se incluye un ejemplo de redacción que **casualmente** resolvería también el problema de concordancia.

Comment: Pero esa es la mision del documento de codigo de conducta, no del equipo que hace el codigo. Lo que estan discutiendo ahi, es que se contradice con la mision de SO, y para eso es la aclaracion..

Comment: @gbianchi Kristina no dice que sea la misión del documento, dice que es la misión de su equipo. Suponiendo sin conceder que tienes razón, me parece que es muy desafortunada la elección de palabras. En el ámbito organizacional el concepto de **misión** es para objetivos de alto nivel no para el de un documento.

Comment: Ruben.. el comentario de cristina creo que queda subsanado con todos los comentarios posteriores... Esta bien lo que decis, pero me parece que ella confundio los terminos. Siempre se habla sobre el documento. y la mision es del sitio.

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias pero aún queda vigente lo dicho en el resumen: opino que deben arreglarlo **lo antes posible**. P.D. Aún no he leído las 75 respuestas ni todos los comentarios a ellas, dudo que lo haga:)

Comment: jajajaj.. hay que mirar por arriba.. pero como esta escrita la mision, a mi, en este momento, me parece bien.

Comment: las discusiones en SOes no van a ser leídas por la gente trabajando en el documento, por lo que lo ideal sería comentarlo en MSE. A no ser que el objetivo de la publicación sea construir consenso acá para llevarlo a MSE, pero no parece algo que afecte en particular a este sitio.

Comment: @g3rv4: Gracias por pasar por acá. Si no lo has hecho aún pasa también por [Si cambian “be nice”, ¿deberíamos tener una discusión respecto al nuevo documento?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3562/65)

Comment: ah, perdón! esta pregunta es para pedir ayuda con su traducción? me parece que sería genial que lo diga la pregunta (y capaz sacar la etiqueta discusión? eso me hizo pensar que el objetivo era discutir el CoC y tu observación)

Comment: @g3rv4 ¡No me limites! :P

Comment: no era la intención limitarte :) sólo quería asegurarme de que tu opinión se escuche!

Comment: Es mi forma de hacer "[rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)". En lugar de llevar un diario escondido en la mesa de noche, para ciertas cosas uso espacios como este, por un lado porque es más fácil que lo encuentre y por otro porque con comentarios como el tuyo me doy cuenta de errores y de formas de enriquecer y sintetizar la publicación :)

Comment: Como bien dice @g3rv4, creo que esta publicación tiene más sentido en [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) donde tendría visibilidad para el equipo que realmente se está encargando de la redacción del nuevo código de conducta.No me parece mal que se pueda discutir aquí ya que nos afecta a todos, pero siempre y cuando la finalidad sea publicarlo en el meta principal :)

Comment: @Pikoh Allá no aceptan publicaciones en español :)

Comment: @Rubén Cuando salga la nueva norma de conducta, tendremos la oportunidad de editarla a nuestros gustos (siempre y cuando el espíritu y el corazón de la original se honre)