# Comentarios e iniciativas en sitios internacionales

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, sitios-internacionales, meta-stackexchange

> Link al original: [Feedback And Initiatives On International Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/141717)

El objetivo final de Stack Overflow es, con la ayuda de nuestra comunidad, crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para cada pregunta de programación. Junto con nuestros valientes usuarios, hemos emprendido una aventura increíble ya que hemos lanzado sitios de Stack Overflow en diferentes idiomas en los últimos años.

[image]

¡Y va bien hasta ahora! Si consideramos los sitios como un sitio internacional unificado, es la segunda comunidad más activa después de SO en ingles (según la métrica de pregunta por día). Al mirar nuestros sitios internacionales y el resto de la red de Stack Exchange, claramente veo que falta algo muy importante que todos los sitios de la red tienen, excepto los internacionales. Me refiero al "*canal de comunicación bidireccional entre la empresa y la comunidad*".

#### ¿Cómo se comunican las comunidades y la empresa actualmente?

Desde el 01/01/2018 (hasta el 15/06/2018), los empleados de la empresa han publicado lo siguiente:

- Meta Stack Exchange: 282 respuestas.
- Meta Stack Overflow en ruso: 48 respuestas.
- Meta Stack Overflow en español: 28 respuestas.
- Meta Stack Overflow en portugués: 10 respuestas.
- Meta Stack Overflow en japonés: 1 respuesta.
- Meta Stack Overflow en inglés: 412 respuestas.

Me parece que si alguien de la compañía no habla el idioma de una comunidad, queda aislado del resto de la red. No queremos que eso suceda. Nuestra filosofía de éxito depende en gran medida de nuestra comunidad. Poco a poco, nuestros sitios se convierten en el mejor lugar para hacer y responder preguntas en Internet en función de sus comentarios. Sin una forma de hablar con una comunidad y escuchar a nuestros usuarios, hay pocas posibilidades de mejorar algo.

#### ¿Cuál fue el proceso?

Al principio, había un administrador de comunidad bilingüe dedicado para cada sitio internacional. La forma en que los administradores de la comunidad trabajaron con las comunidades difería de un sitio a otro. Cada sitio internacional tenía diferentes iniciativas y enfoques diferentes que casi nunca se han cruzado. Eso significa que los CM a menudo hacían el mismo trabajo para resolver problemas similares en los sitios internacionales. Se podría haber ahorrado mucha energía trabajando juntos.

#### Mejora de las comunicaciones

¿Qué pasa si hacemos las cosas de otra manera? ¿Qué pasaría si pudiéramos compartir iniciativas entre sitios internacionales, reutilizar la experiencia de otras comunidades y actuar en función de los comentarios de todos los sitios? El primer paso hacia este objetivo es establecer un canal de comunicación para intercambiar ideas, iniciativas y retroalimentación entre la empresa y las comunidades, así como entre las mismas comunidades.

El mayor desafío en la situación es el hecho de que todas las comunidades, incluida la empresa, hablan diferentes idiomas. No es culpa de nadie, pero esa es la realidad. Debido a esto, me gustaría compartir algunas reflexiones sobre cómo podría funcionar el canal de comunicación.

## Comentarios e iniciativas en sitios internacionales

> **TL; DR**
>
> - Necesitamos un canal para la comunicación entre la compañía y las comunidades internacionales, así como para las comunidades internacionales entre sí. Actualmente, el mejor lugar para esto es MSE.
> - El inglés se usará en las discusiones de MSE y los sitios internacionales mantendrán discusiones en sus propios idiomas localizados.
> - Las iniciativas de la compañía se compartirán en inglés en MSE y necesitaremos la ayuda de traductores voluntarios para publicar versiones traducidas en sus respectivos sitios meta.
> - Las iniciativas comunitarias se compartirán en sus respectivos meta sitios y deberán traducirse para MSE. Luego, pueden diseminarse a través de todos los otros metas internacionales como se mencionó anteriormente.
> - Mantendremos sincronizadas las discusiones en todos los meta sitios.
> - Cuando un debate sobre un meta sitio internacional está casi terminado, necesitamos la ayuda de los voluntarios nuevamente para hacer un resumen de lo que dijo la comunidad internacional y publicarlo como una respuesta en MSE.

[image]

En los últimos años en SOru hemos intentado implementar muchas iniciativas interesantes ([por ejemplo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6)), comenzamos muchas iniciativas sociales ([por ejemplo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4191/6)), integramos/activamos algunas características interesantes del motor ([por ejemplo](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7095/6)). Me molesta que la mayoría de esas iniciativas ni siquiera se hayan sugerido a otras comunidades internacionales. Tiendo a creer que la situación es la misma en los otros sitios: cada sitio tiene su propio conjunto de iniciativas que nadie conoce, excepto los usuarios del sitio.

Eso podría llevar a una situación en la que las características muy importantes para las comunidades internacionales no se implementen en el motor porque las iniciativas parecen ser necesarias para un número relativamente pequeño de usuarios (si los vemos en el contexto de sitios internacionales individuales). Cada uno de nuestros sitios internacionales no es solo grande, pero, como se dijo, juntos somos la segunda comunidad más activa en la red. Si todas las comunidades necesitan una característica en el motor, mi esperanza es que obtenga la prioridad correcta. El primer paso, sin embargo, es comenzar a discutir iniciativas juntos.

#### ¿Cómo podemos propagar una iniciativa en todos los sitios internacionales?

Cuando pensamos en formas de comunicarnos en los sitios, debemos considerar lo siguiente:

- El proceso debe ser escalable. Imagínese, que tenemos cien sitios internacionales. El proceso debería funcionar para cualquier cantidad de sitios sin dificultades.
- El autor de una iniciativa no habla todos los idiomas de nuestros sitios internacionales.
- Queremos que haya tantas personas interesadas en una iniciativa como sea posible, incluidos nuestros usuarios de diversas comunidades de habla inglesa y empleados de la empresa.
- Debería haber una manera para que las comunidades internacionales discutan una iniciativa en sus propios idiomas.
- El resultado de las discusiones sobre meta sitios internacionales debe ser compartido con el resto de la red, y particularmente con los otros sitios internacionales.

Con esto en mente, me gustaría compartir algunas reflexiones sobre cómo se vería el proceso:

1. El autor de una iniciativa (un CM o un usuario) necesita publicar una pregunta en MSE con una etiqueta especial (digamos [meta-tag: internacional]). El idioma de la publicación siempre debe ser inglés.
2. Los usuarios que conocen dos idiomas pueden ser voluntarios para traducir la pregunta y publicar la versión traducida en un meta sitio internacional.
3. Cuando la traducción se publica en un meta sitio internacional, el voluntario agrega un enlace a la pregunta sobre MSE. Además, agregue el enlace a la pregunta MSE a la traducida. Debería ayudarnos a mantener sincronizada la discusión sobre metas.
4. Después de que una comunidad discuta la iniciativa, necesitamos un voluntario que publique un resumen de la meta-discusión internacional como respuesta a la pregunta sobre MSE. El resumen debe estar en inglés. Creo que podría ser una buena idea tener una respuesta wiki donde haya resúmenes de todos los meta sitios internacionales. En este caso, podemos mantener la respuesta sobre otras respuestas al aceptarla.
5. Si alguien tiene alguna idea sobre la iniciativa, puede responder sobre cualquier meta, incluido MSE.

En el caso de una iniciativa comunitaria, el proceso es casi igual con una sola diferencia: la iniciativa se inicia en un meta sitio internacional y debe traducirse al inglés y publicarse en MSE. Después de eso todo es lo mismo.

Tener este proceso le permite a la compañía entender lo que necesitan las comunidades internacionales. Además, el proceso debería ayudar a nuestras comunidades internacionales a intercambiar ideas sobre sus propios problemas específicos, compartir iniciativas y observar las cosas increíbles que están sucediendo con los desbordamientos internacionales de pilas.

### Por favor, cuéntanos qué piensas

Queremos que nuestros sitios internacionales sean el mejor lugar en Internet para hacer preguntas de programación en los primeros idiomas de los usuarios. El primer paso es crear una forma para que las comunidades se comuniquen entre sí y con la compañía. Si tiene alguna idea sobre cómo podemos mejorar los procesos con respecto a este objetivo, ¡comparta sus ideas!

Comment: TL;DR: Si antes en los sitios internacionales costaba llegar a conseguir algo, ahora lo complicamos un poco más obligando a tener dos debates paralelos. Si los sitios internacionales nacieron para que la gente no tuviera que tirar del inglés, ahora hacemos necesaria la dualidad para intentar conseguir algo... La verdad es que suena un poco desastroso.

Comment: @fedorqui no se, yo lo entiendo de otra manera diferente. No se trata de que se consigan cosas específicas para los sitios internacionales, sino de que los usuarios de sitios internacionales que no sepan inglés puedan participar en cuestiones que afectan a todos los sitios. Si es asi, a mi no me parece mal. Si es como tu lo pintas, efectivamente es un desastre

Comment: @Pikoh a mí me parece que se está haciendo lo inevitable: concentrar todas las peticiones en Meta.SE. Es lo más lógico y razonable. Sin embargo, durante unos años [se nos vendió](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3565/#comment12773_3565) que desde aquí, desde MetaSOes, tendríamos nuestro peso en los debates colectivos, cuando no era así. Simplemente es ajustar la mentalidad y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: @Pikoh supongo que quisieron copiar la lógica que se usa en SO, donde Meta es muy potente, los CM muy activos por allí y un buen lugar para generar iniciativas que pueden contrastarse y debatirse rápidamente. Sin embargo, considero que en nuestro caso tener un CM propio ha implicado que lanzar una propuesta consistía en esperar que él hiciera de filtro y lo elevara al limbo de lo desconocido, lo que a la práctica se ha convertido en que casi todo quedara en el aire. Lo que veo inviable es tener el mismo debate en paralelo en todos los metas internacionales, simplemente no es práctico.

Comment: Yo entendi que la idea es centralizar un repositorio justamente de ideas entre los sitios internacionales. Asi como nosotros tenemos traducir, y no fue exportado a ninguna lado por el CM en su momento, al parecer en Ru tienen otras cosas de las cuales nosotros ni idea. De esta forma, si encontramos un bug aca, lo informamos a los otros 3, y ellos detectan lo mismo, tenemos mas fuerza para presionar que si somos uno solo...

Comment: @gbianchi buen punto. De hecho [contesté a la pregunta original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315353/209901) comentando que sería buena hacer inventario de qué tiene cada comunidad, más que nada porque lo mismo podemos tener cosas que otras ya tienen y simplemente no sabemos que podemos tener :)

Comment: @fedorqui efectivamente, creo que se quiere concentrar todo en Meta SE porque lo que se habla en los meta de los sitios internacionales no tiene ninguna trascendecia. Por eso digo que a priori a mi no me parece mal, siempre y cuando sirva para algo claro. Muy bueno tu ejemplo de los audits en la respuesta que pusiste al post

Comment: @Pikoh ajá, entiendo. Visto así a mí tampoco, me parece una dosis de realismo. Lo que sí veo desastroso, como decía en mi primer comentario, es esto de ir traduciendo el debate aquí y allá.

Comment: @fedorqui si,no parece lo ideal. Yo ya puse una objeción en la pregunta original sobre "resumir" lo que se hable en un meta internacional en metaSE. El resumen puede estar contaminado por la opinion del que lo traduzca. De todas maneras es todo mi interpretación, no es exactamente que motiva esta iniciativa :)

Answer (score 3):

Punto y aparte de la retroalimentación que le demos a "la compañía", nosotros podríamos acordar de una vez cómo queremos identificar los temas que serán "comunicados a la compañía". Lo más sencillo sería usar una etiqueta específica, el asunto es cuál. Por lo pronto me animé a agregar [meta-stackexchange](/questions/tagged/meta-stackexchange) a esta pregunta.

> Actualización: Hoy agregué [sitios-internacionales](/questions/tagged/sitios-internacionales) a esta y otras publicaciones de Nicolas que han sido traducidas como símil de la etiqueta "international-sites" de MSE.

Por otro lado, y siguiendo el tenor de la respuesta de gbianchi, yo contesté la pregunta en MSE varias veces. A continuación los enlaces en orden cronológico (mas antigua primero)

- Cosas que hacen falta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315461/289691

  - Mejores etiquetas
  - Seguimiento de estado
  - Chat room
  - Embajadores
- Vocabulario y etiquetas: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315479/289691

  - internacional es muy ambiguo y por ende una etiqueta international lo es también. Mejor usar `localized`.
- Propuesta de cambio de título https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315500/289691

  - La pregunta original sólo se refiere a Stack Overflow y los Stack Overflow en los diferentes idiomas. Recién se agregó el sitio sobre el idioma ruso en ruso.

Relacionado con lo anterior estoy solicitando que en MSE la etiqueta `internacional` sea convertida en sinónimo de la etiqueta `internationalization` en [Make [international] a synonym of [internationalization]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315476/289691)

Comment: [He añadido el sinónimo tal y como fue  sugerido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/internationalization/synonyms).  Falta nada más que se vote a favor.

Comment: @JuanM Gracias a esperar y mientras tanto a hacer puntos en `internationalization` para poder votar :D

Answer (score 0):

Deberiamos ordenar las ideas...

Yo no conteste la pregunta original, pero para mi deberia haber dos cosas:

- Una sala de chat, para cosas mas rapidas
- Un meta propio de sitios internacionales, para discutir errores, bugs y cosas que solo impactan los sitios en otros idiomas.

Comment: No creo que una respuesta como esta debería ser wiki. Dejando eso de lado, estoy de acuerdo con tener una sala de chat oficial dedicada a atender los asuntos particulares de los sitios internacionales, en cuanto al meta propio no creo que haga falta, sólo con tener las etiquetas apropiadas en [meta.se] es suficiente, al menos para empezar.

Comment: Ruben, lo que remarcaron y me parecio correcto, es que nuestro ruido puede provocar lio en meta.se, porque primero hay muchos que no van a hablar un ingles fluido, y hay muchos temas particulares que pueden ser mal entendidos por la comunidad de alli. alguien que no sepa que esos tags son particulares para nosotros, puede votar negativo algo que para nosotros no lo es...

Comment: En mi humilde opinión un Meta específico para los sitios internacionales no debería ser declarado como un prioridad de las comunidades internacionales en particular cuando lo que está de fondo es que hay menos recursos destinados a ellas. El que haya muchos que no hablan inglés fluido ocurría antes de los sitios internacionales y es independiente de estos, igual pasa con lo de temas mal entendidos y mal votados.

Comment: @Rubén al ser una pregunta en modo Wiki, las respuestas se marcan como tal automáticamente.

Comment: @fedorqui gracias por la aclaración.