# A la propuesta del código de conducta le falta incluir como expectativa la aceptación de la votación

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, código-de-conducta

## Resumen

Agregar a las expectativas del nuevo Código de Conducta que tanto los que vienen para recibir ayuda como los que vienen para dar ayuda deben tener una actitud de aceptación del funcionamiento de los votos en la red de Stack Exchange

## Explicación

[We'd like your feedback on our new Code of Conduct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038/289691) se convoca a la comunidad de la red de Stack Exchange a dar comentarios sobre la propuesta de un nuevo código de conducta para la red de Stack Exchange.

La propuesta actual del código de conducta sólo menciona de forma explícita los votos en algunos ejemplos de la sección de reportes y cumplimiento

---

> “Good grief, people voted this question up?”

traducción de Google Translate

> "Dios mío, la gente votó esta pregunta?"

---

> Using “sock puppet” voting to game the reputation system

traducción

> Votar usando "cuentas títere" para corromper el sistema de reputación

---

Los que tenemos tiempo en la red de Stack Exchange sabemos que los votos son la causa de que algunos usuarios se sientan agraviados. Se ha destacado en meta en varias ocasiones los casos de primeras preguntas que reciben votos negativos al poco tiempo de ser publicada pero también ocurre en usuarios con una reputación relativamente alta.

Siendo la votación uno de los elementos fundamentales del modelo de Stack Exchange, la actitud hacia la misma es muy importante así como el reflejo de esta en comentarios, preguntas, respuestas, chats, reportes y en la votación misma.

Por el momento no tengo una sugerencia específica sobre cómo incorporar que esta aceptación es requerida, salvo el incluir esta mención en la sección de expectativas.

### Respuestas allá que mencionan algo relacionado

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312044/289691
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312062/289691
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312065/289691

---

Punto y aparte de lo anterior es el estar de acuerdo o no con los votos que haya recibido una publicación en particular, el conjunto de votos recibidos por las publicaciones en una etiqueta o de un usuario.

## Relacionado

- [Si cambian "be nice", ¿deberíamos tener una discusión respecto al nuevo documento?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3562/65)

Comment: Queres que propongamos algo del tipo, ser amistoso tambien es votar cuando corresponde?

Comment: @gbianchi ¡Muy buena forma de plantearlo!

Comment: mmm.. JuanM podra redactarla mejor? (no es que quiera pasarle el trabajo, quiero que se entienda bien...)

Comment: @gbianchi Esta [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312044/289691) de allá menciona algo relacionado

Answer (score 1):

Como hoy es la fecha límite publiqué allá https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312489/289691

Dice algo así como lo siguiente:

Mientras que el Código de Conducta está centrado en comportamientos observables, debería hacer mayor énfasis en la importancia de la votación en el modelo de la Red de Stack Exchange como se indica en Vota pronto, vota frecuentemente.

Tal vez decir algo como

> - Se amigable votando pronto y frecuentemente
> - La Comunidad muestra su amabilidad votando pronto y frecuentemente

En cuanto a las reacciones a los votos

> Está bien que muestres tu desagrado con los votos recibidos en tus publicaciones o las publicaciones de otros pero hazlo sin usar sarcasmo ni ironía pues es difícil identificar si se ha hecho con un tono amable o si es un abuso.