# ¿Qué ocurre si alguien empieza a traducir todas la preguntas y respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Según esta [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-directas-de-respuestas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl) y [esta otra](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%C3%A9s), si es aceptable traducir las preguntas y respuestas del sitio StackOverflow en inglés. Pero, ¿qué ocurriría (y es muy posible que suceda) si alguien empieza a traducir todas y cada una de las preguntas ya existentes en el sitio en inglés? Muy probablemente la persona que haga eso empiece a ganar muchos y muchos puntos.

¿Esto se recomendaría? ¿Se cerrarían las preguntas?

Comment: @WilfredoP no es duplicado ya que esa pregunta se refiere a los mensajes de error en específico.

Comment: Esta pregunta está de manera similar en dos post's del meta actualmente. Por otro lado, falta traducir el "possible duplicate of" xD. Hay que reportarlo no?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Si eso es lo que pasa colocan la pregunta exactamente igual y cuando lees el cuerpo de la pregunta y es casi lo mismo, por eso la reporte.

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta, espero que se note la diferencia.

Comment: @Christian, cual de las tres es tu pregunta final?, en cualquiera de los 3 casos solo la última (¿Se cerrarían las preguntas?) parece tener una respuesta distinta pero increíblemente ligada con los dos post precedentes que mencionas, por lo que a mi entender, sería bueno más bien editar alguna buena respuesta de uno o dos de las preguntas que citas (que por cierto esos dos post para mí serían uno).

Comment: ¿Todas y cada una? Son diez millones de preguntas... buena suerte con la tarea. :-)

Comment: @Konamiman y ahora casi 19 millones de preguntas. No solo que no podría una sola persona, si no que ni toda nuestra comunidad podría ya que ellos son muchos más, casi 12 millones de usuarios, y acá solo 100 mil usuarios.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pues en mi opinion si alguien se da el trabajo de hacer esto le está haciendo un bien a la comunidad de Stackoverflow en español al aumentar el contenido útil en el sitio y merece la reputación que otros usuarios le puedan dar.

Eso sí siempre y cuando se incluya la atribución al autor original como link a la pregnta o respuesta ya que el contenido de StackOverflow usa la licencia  [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.es) con atribución requerida que exije que se de crédito al autor original.

Comment: Carlos pero mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿La reputación se gana por el conocimiento o por traducir? creo que ahí esta el dilema en SO ingles y portugués creo que las personas que tienen alta reputación es por conocimiento no por traducir.

Comment: Buen punto, como dice Carlos Muñoz se podría valorar el esfuerzo de hacer una traducción de calidad. Pero, ¿tendría el mismo valor traducir una respuesta que escribir una respuesta propia?

Comment: @WilfredoP El incluir contenido no disponible previamente en el sitio independientemente de si es traducido o no es una actividad valiosa que de aumenta el conocimiento en este sitio. Por ahora puede parecer que es una forma fácil de ganar reputación pero te aseguro que cuando el sitio deje la beta privada, los usuarios estarán más preocupados en escribir sus propias preguntas a los problemas reales que afronten por lo que los expertos se dedicarán a responder estos en lugar de dedicarse a la traducción.

Comment: @Christian técnicamente si tiene el mismo valor puesto que no es una funcionalidad del sitio indicar si una respuesta es una traducción o no y viéndolo por el lado práctico también ya que los usuarios valoran la existencia de la respuesta más no su origen

Comment: Christhian, quien dijo eso fue @Wilfredo P. Por otro lado, Carlos Muños, siguiente esa lógica se perdería lo que me parece que es el concepto de "reputación" del sitio, es decir, quien más reputación tenga en base a un determinado topico en su perfil, puede ser considerado un referente en dicho tema, tendré que revisar que dice acerca de la reputación SO, quiero creer que estoy errado y más solo se trate de un indicador de aporte dentro del sitio, estoy seguro que más de uno piensa como yo y se confunde.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla bueno en ese punto si tienes razón, sin embargo alguien que coloca una respuesta sea traducción o no debe ser capaz de sustentar la respuesta ya que es muy probable que salgan dudas adicionales en los comentarios. Si alguien no es capaz de sustentar su respuesta es muy probable que otros usuarios detallen mejor sus respuestas y sobrepasen en reputación a la respuesta traducida

Comment: Sí, correcto, en cualquier caso con todos esos inconvenientes dudo que alguien que no sea capaz de responder una pregunta específica, sólo la traduzca tanto para preguntas como para respuesta, además de dejar el link de referencia, y el solo hecho de traducirla ya conlleva tener cierto conocimiento mínimo, igual la beta está para eso, evaluar la calidad de la comunidad también.

Comment: Apuesto que habrán personas que traducirán por traducir (para obtener puntos). Habría que definir si cualquiera podría traducir cualquier pregunta, o necesariamente alguien que conozca del tema.

Comment: @Christian es así, y ese es mi temor, la calidad se ira al demonio si no se tiene eso bien vigilado. Ademas considero que se creara problemas con S.O Carreras.

Comment: Yo pienso que en esta fase de beta principalmente se van a traducir muchas preguntas del SO en inglés, posiblemente con algunas variaciones y el porcentaje de contenido original va a ser bastante bajo; considero que eso no está mal ya que una de las finalidades de la beta es enriquecer el banco de preguntas y respuestas. Pero cuando se consolide SO en español en su versión definitiva el contenido original incrementará de manera exponencial porque habrá muchos usuarios hispanohablantes que se entusiasmen a preguntar y responder en español al ver la alta calidad del contenido del sitio.

Answer (score 4):

Primero lo primero: **es válido** traducir todas las preguntas y respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés, y probablemente quien lo haga **reciba miles de puntos**.

Si les interesa mi opinión, me parece *perfecto* que así ocurra. El objetivo de es.SO es satisfacer la misma necesidad que el SO original para la gente que no puede acceder al SO original por la única barrera que los distingue: el idioma.

Entonces, ¿qué mejor que poner todo el conocimiento acumulado y depurado de **años** trabajo de SO al alcance de gente que no puede accederlo? **¿Por qué no premiarían a quien se tome el trabajo de cubrir ese *gap*?**

El botón de upvote tanto de preguntas como de respuestas tiene una parte en común: *es útil y clara*. Es discutible afirmar que una pregunta traducida del sitio original *demuestra trabajo de investigación*, pero sí es útil tener en español una pregunta que antes sólo existía en inglés.

Por los comentarios, el otro *miedo* que percibo es a que **el sitio no logre formar su propia comunidad** y se limite a ser una buena traducción de StackOverflow. Incluso Braiam menciona en su respuesta que los otros SO traducidos formaron una comunidad, y que haciendo esto nosotros perderíamos la posibilidad de formar la nuestra. Buen, acá sí hice algo de investigación: [la pregunta número 11 en meta.pt.SO](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11/36588) fue bastante similar a esta que estamos discutiendo, y aún así lograron formar su comunidad :) (apostaría a que los rusos y japoneses habrán lidiado pronto con este problema, también, pero de esos idiomas *no cazo un fulbo* como para buscar :)

No podemos *limitarnos* a traducir preguntas de los otros SO. Primero, porque nos aburriríamos. Y, segundo, porque eventualmente va a llegar acá gente que está buscando ayuda con un problema, *en español*, y encuentre una solución. Tal como nosotros llegamos al SO original. Y, ¿adivinen qué? Cuando esa gente tenga dudas, va a preguntar acá, sin traducir ninguna pregunta de ningún lado. *Ahí va a fortalecerse la comunidad*.

Si tenemos gente que se tome el trabajo de traducir preguntas del SO en inglés (o portugués, o ruso, o japonés, o...) y esas preguntas son las que encuentren los futuros usuarios de es.SO que no pueden ser usuarios de otros SO por cuestiones de idioma, entonces ahí vamos a tener **gente que pertenezca únicamente a esta comunidad**. Y va a ser esa gente la que marque *la mayor diferencia* con todos los otros SO - y esa diferencia será la que haga que más hispanoparlantes del SO original decidan participar de es.SO, porque ya **no va a ser *una copia* del original, si no que va a tener un tinte propio**.

No van 24 horas del sitio, y ya estamos preocupándonos por cómo vamos a fracasar como comunidad. Concentrémonos en aportar, por ahora - ya habrá tiempo para refactorearnos :)

Comment: Tu mal interpretas tanto my respuesta como la de Gabe en pt.SO. Yo estoy en contra de la traducción mera y simple, al igual que Gabe, por las mismas razones: "Primero porque de esa forma no nos estamos creando *nuestro* sitio, y segundo porque eso crea un ambiente poco amistoso para el que esta llegando, ya que las "verdaderas" preguntas acabaran sumergidas en un sitio lleno de preguntas famosas." La preocupación de que no nos formemos como comunidad esta ahí, y siendo un reflejo de SO no crea una comunidad propia.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Qué ocurre si alguien empieza a traducir todas la preguntas y respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?

Tendremos que considerar seriamente si realmente necesitamos Stack Overflow en Español, ya que ¿para que invertir tiempo en algo que puede ser facilmente realizado con simplemente pasar Stack Overflow por el traductor de Google y listo? Y lo que más me molesta es que otros betas (ya sean SO en otros idiomas o simplemente nuevos sitios en inglés) pueden crear contenido nuevo, sin necesidad de traducir o copiar nada. **¿POR QUE NOSOTROS NO PODEMOS HACERLO?** ¿Es que no tenemos la capacidad de formular nuestras propias preguntas? ¿O simplemente no podemos poner dedicación en hacer que esto funcione? Yo espero que no sea asi, por que de otro modo le espera un futuro bien oscuro a es.SO.

Comment: +1 con tu comentario, Justo estaba escribiendo una respuesta algo similar, yo creo que se puede tomar como fuente una pregunta "X" pero no considero que tengas 543K de reputación con preguntas solo traducidas y no sepas nada del tema, por ejemplo, ¿Donde quedaría la reputación del sitio? Considero que es un tema un poco delicado y se esta tomando a la ligera, porque lo que dice en otras respuestas es que ahorita se hace porque son pocas, pero eso no importa, en futuro tomas un tag puede ser Javascript o Android y empiezas a traducir y ya todo se va al demonio.

Comment: -1. Si piensan "¿para que invertir tiempo en algo que puede ser facilmente realizado con simplemente pasar Stack Overflow por el traductor de Google y listo?", relean [el anuncio de StackOverflow en japonés](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/). Si siguen pensando igual, quizá esta no sea la comunidad en que mejor puedan invertir su tiempo.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia cual es tu punto?

Comment: @Braiam justo [lo estaba escribiendo](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/78/75) :)

Comment: -1: Como ya ha dicho @mgarciaisaia esta pregunta ha sido contestada docenas de veces. En particular, la traducción automática no sirve.

Comment: @astrojuanlu yo no entiendo que es lo que tu interpretas. Me lo puedes explicar?

Comment: En el artículo enlazado: "Well, when last we spoke of creating non-English versions of Stack Overflow, some of you were certain we should've gone the easy route and just leveraged a machine translation service instead of creating real sites for real people to use. I humbly invite you to read the rest of this post using the mechanical babelfish of your choice, and see if you think such tools can be relied on for important work...".

Comment: @astrojuanlu no me estas diciendo nada. Cual es mi punto de vista en tu opinion?

Comment: @Braiam, has escrito: "¿para que invertir tiempo en algo que puede ser facilmente realizado con simplemente pasar Stack Overflow por el traductor de Google y listo?". Y yo te estoy diciendo: **el traductor de Google no vale para nada**. Haz lo que pone en el artículo, que es traducirlo de manera automática, y observa que **no tiene ningún sentido**. Ya no sé cómo decirlo más claro.

Comment: @astrojuanlu no estas entendiendo el sarcasmo? Dije, que si a lo que nos vamos a dedicar es a simplemente traducir SO, sería más eficiente que usemos servicios de traducción automatizados y dejemos esto.

Answer (score 0):

Según he entendido, en base a lo que se ha comentado en las dos preguntas que has mencionado, no surge ningún conflicto al hacer esto.

Tanto si la gente lo hace por la reputación (que no deja de ser un número al lado de tu nombre), como si realmente lo hace por ayudar a la comunidad, **el resultado es el mismo**: la cantidad de información de SOes aumenta.

Por lo tanto, mi conclusión es que **sí, se puede hacer sin problema**.