# Debo dirigir al sitio en inglés o se trata un poco más de construir la base en español

Tags: soporte, convenciones-sociales, código-de-conducta

Por alguna razón me enteré hace poco de que había una alternativa en español de SO y había olvidado de regresar hasta hoy. Tiene ya algunos meses que soy usuario ferviente en la comunidad inglesa y estoy muy acostumbrado a la, digamos, hostilidad y frialdad con la que se manejan allá y en general a su forma de levantar flags, comentar cuando una pregunta está fuera de lugar, y hasta qué grado se debe ayudar al OP. Pero una mirada rápida aquí me hace pensar que no es el mismo grado. Mi duda es hasta qué grado debo, por ejemplo, dirigir al sitio en inglés cuando es obvio que allá está y tiene cientos de votos, o si se trata un poco más de construir la base en español. En caso de que sea más lo segundo, hasta qué grado educar cuando la pregunta es muy básica.

Me imagino que muchos estarán enterados, pero allá últimamente se trata de muchas preguntas de poca utilidad, muchas veces por falta de leer las clásulas pero también por mucha flojera de elaborar un simple query para meter en google o en el mismo SO. Si no me expliqué bien (allá me suele pasar) con gusto háganmelo saber.

**EDIT**

Creo que debo ahondar antes en un par de cosas. Por ejemplo, estoy acostumbrado a que cuando la pregunta es básicamente "debugueen mi código" o "no se cómo hacer esto y no pongo código" la pregunta se va directamente al caño. O aunque tenga un poco de base y contexto pero es obvio que no se ha puesto a ver cómo hacer funcionar el código del tutorial que vio y sólo vino a que se lo resolviéramos también. Se que mi pregunta es aún un poco subjetiva, pero cualquier comentario se los agradeceré.

*Ejemplo*

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36975/consulta-a-base-de-datos-muy-complicada-en-mysql) me encantaría ganarme unos puntitos gratis. Y aunqyue también me encantaría ayudarlo no hace falta saber inglés para googlear sobre el tema y en una de esas hasta le sale el ejemplo hecho. Y según mi costumbre esta se cierra y ya debería tener al menos un -2 o -3 y estar flaggeada, más cuando un usuario 3K ya le hizo un edit.

Gracias.

Comment: 1. Estamos trabajando en el sarcasmo y la agresividad, pero todavía somos una comunidad muy joven. 2. Por lo mismo somos más tolerantes, buscamos mejorar la relación preguntas/respuestas y respuestas/aceptación. 3. Nuestro alcance es más amplio, aceptamos preguntas que en SO son off-topic, básicamente somos una mezcla de varios sitios de SE enfocados en programación, pero verás desde Databases hasta SEO. 4. Usamos con discreción los votos, tanto positivos como negativos, pero también estamos trabajando en ello. 5. Pues bienvenido.

Comment: gracias @toledano por tomarte el tiempo de responder

Comment: StackOverflow en español no necesariamente tiene que ser idéntica a StackOverflow, eso ya se ha hablado demasiado en Meta 

Comment: @x4mp73r por eso primero preferí preguntar, te ofrezco una disculpa por tener flojera de buscar todos los posts relacionados, leerlos y sacar conclusiones para poder empezar a contribuir.

Comment: ¡¿Disculpa porqué?! No pasa nada amigo 

Answer (score 1):

En síntesis, se trata de **contribuir contenido en español**.

El contenido de las publicaciones en Stack Overflow en español no tiene que ser inédito ni del todo original. Puede estar en Stack Overflow en inglés, en ruso, portugués, en algún otro sitio de la red de Stack Exchange o bien en casi cualquier otra parte<sup>1</sup>. No importa si se puede encontrar o no fácilmente "googleando", lo que sí debemos procurar es que las publicaciones sigan tanto los lineamientos oficiales como las convenciones establecidas por la propia comunidad de Stack Overflow en español.

Como mencionó toledano en un [comentario hace tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128/dudas-sobre-el-protocolo?rq=1#comment2818_1128), estamos trabajando en varios aspectos para hacer el sitio y la comunidad mejor.

> <sup>1</sup> Si se va a usar contenido de otro, debe hacerse la atribución del mismo para no caer en plagio, véase [Cómo referir material a otros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Además debe cuidarse de no infringir ni Copyright, ni licencias como [las de Creative Commons](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licencias_Creative_Commons).

**Preguntas relacionadas**

- [¿Son aceptables las traducciones directas de respuestas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/14/65)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Rubén. Desafortunadamente perdí el interés de contribuir debido a la holgura con la que se manejan las banderas y a la calidad de las preguntas. Mis mejores deseos a la comunidad

Comment: Entiendo. Ojalá más pronto que tarde alcemos los estándares que hagan este sitio y a su comunidad la mejores en su tipo en español.